# jquery ajax getJson onSuccess use a function from the response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a js script simply getting a basic Json content page.js

```
{
"desc":"",
**"save":function(){alert(0);}**
}
```

then on `success:function(data)` I simply wanted to do `data.save()`
but the **onsuccess never gets called ?**

**'complete' does though but still my save function isn't evaluated ?**

I tried writting it as a string : `"save":"function(){alert(0);}"`
and applying it to `eval` onSuccess , but strangely it says function has no name

**Is this a limitation -- we can't pass functions as part of the json reponse object?**

even less execute them ?
or am I simply doing something wrong

Thanks for the insight

Comment: Yes, it is a limitation of JSON that it only works with values, not functions.  Your workaround should work with some tweaks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a pure data definition language, so functions can not be part of a JSON object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results). Using `eval()` might work, but I'd strongly discourage you to use it, since it is [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea). I'd propose you implement the behavior you want in an object, and then set the state of this object using the JSON you got from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can just eval `alert(0)`, it should work (and set this as your "save" string in the JSON)

But you should avoid using eval as a workaround

Edit : this has already been answered here : [Is it valid to define functions in JSON results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results)