# Trying to display date and number value

Tags: php, string, date, datetime, highcharts

Trying to display this below to print out

```
[Date.UTC(09:54:36),15297]
```

so I can use the data in highcharts.

```
/* Retrieve and display the results of the query. */

$Hour = '';
$ActualLoadMW = '';
$finalString = '';
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //echo $row['Hour'].", ".$row['ActualLoadMW']."\n";
    $Hour= $Hour.", ".convertTime($row['Hour']);
    $ActualLoadMW = $ActualLoadMW.", ".$row['ActualLoadMW'];

    $finalString = $finalString.", [Date.UTC"."(".convertTime($row['Hour']).$row['ActualLoadMW'];
}
```

Comment: So what are you getting instead?

Comment: [Date.UTC(10:15:0015425, [Date.UTC(09:54:3615297,

Comment: I know its my syntax, just can't get it to print correct

Comment: so i guess your query gets two results back, and since it is inside the loop you get the date two times. if you don't want that behaviour maybe you need to move $finalString = ''; inside the loop

Comment: those are just an example of what I am getting back, I need it to look like [Date.UTC (time value), other Value], and so on but I can't get the other ) and ] to show up I don't know where to place it in the $finalString section

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Date.UTC() in json, because it is string, so as a result function is not called. I advice to familiar with JSON structure and general characteristics.

[Is it valid to define functions in JSON results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results)