# Deserializing an enum with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying and failing to deserialize an enum with Jackson 2.5.4, and I don't quite see my case out there. My input strings are camel case, and I want to simply map to standard Enum conventions.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
public enum Status {
    READY("ready"),
    NOT_READY("notReady"),
    NOT_READY_AT_ALL("notReadyAtAll");

    private static Map<String, Status> FORMAT_MAP = Stream
            .of(Status.values())
            .collect(toMap(s -> s.formatted, Function.<Status>identity()));

    private final String formatted;

    Status(String formatted) {
        this.formatted = formatted;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Status fromString(String string) {
        Status status = FORMAT_MAP.get(string);
        if (status == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(string + " has no corresponding value");
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

I've also tried `@JsonValue` on a getter to no avail, which was an option I saw reported elsewhere. They all blow up with:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of ...Status from String value 'ready': value not one of declared Enum instance names: ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, I wish this were true, but it certainly still blows up -- I just checked. I think it can't deal with the variety of cases.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: Same -- "value not one of the declared Enum instance names"

Comment: How about if you try "READY"?

Comment: @Simon, sure it works then if all your JSON values match perfectly -- but I'm deserializing and don't have the luxury of changing the inputs!

Answer (score 172, accepted):

**EDIT:** Starting from Jackson 2.6, you can use `@JsonProperty` on each element of the enum to specify its serialization/deserialization value ([see here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/677)):

```
public enum Status {
    @JsonProperty("ready")
    READY,
    @JsonProperty("notReady")
    NOT_READY,
    @JsonProperty("notReadyAtAll")
    NOT_READY_AT_ALL;
}
```

---

(The rest of this answer is still valid for older versions of Jackson)

You should use `@JsonCreator` to annotate a static method that receives a `String` argument. That's what Jackson calls a *factory method*:

```
public enum Status {
    READY("ready"),
    NOT_READY("notReady"),
    NOT_READY_AT_ALL("notReadyAtAll");

    private static Map<String, Status> FORMAT_MAP = Stream
        .of(Status.values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.formatted, Function.identity()));

    private final String formatted;

    Status(String formatted) {
        this.formatted = formatted;
    }

    @JsonCreator // This is the factory method and must be static
    public static Status fromString(String string) {
        return Optional
            .ofNullable(FORMAT_MAP.get(string))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(string));
    }
}
```

This is the test:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Status s1 = mapper.readValue("\"ready\"", Status.class);
Status s2 = mapper.readValue("\"notReadyAtAll\"", Status.class);

System.out.println(s1); // READY
System.out.println(s2); // NOT_READY_AT_ALL
```

As the factory method expects a `String`, you have to use JSON valid syntax for strings, which is to have the value quoted.

Comment: Ugh I just realized it was an instance method in my example this whole time. Sloppy. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I want Jackson to deserialize `READY`, `NOT_READY`, and `NOT_READY_AT_ALL` addditionally to `ready`, `notReady`, and `notReadyAtAll`. How can I do it? I may insert `try { return Status.valueOf(string); } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}` 
at the start of fromString(). Is there a better solution?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I want to deserialize both.

Comment: @JohannesFlügel I'd just modify the factory method: if the string argument is not in the map, I'd try with `Status.valueOf`. In one line: `return Optional.ofNullable(FORMAT_MAP.get(string)).orElseGet(() -> Status.valueOf(string));`

Comment: Except in the code above, you are trying to access an instance variable "formatted" from within a static context. It won't compile this way

Comment: How can you do the @JsonCreator method in Kotlin?

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I actually had one library that was built with newer jackson and uses @ JsonProperty. But some of my dependencies were pulling older jackson (2.5.x). So code compiled just fine but @JsonProperty value wasn't honored and instead enum constant name was used ("AAA" instead of "aaa" specified in @ JsonProperty).

Comment: @interrupt Glad you notice the issue. You were another victim of dependency hell... If you are using maven, you should fix the version in the dependency management section of your master pom.

Comment: My input is a xml, how can i achieve it for xml ?

Comment: @MohamedThoufeeque Hi! Sorry, I've never used Jackson for XML.

Comment: this works only if you have only one field and if JsonFormat shape is not as object.
this is for multiple fields and @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
@JsonCreator
    static PinOperationMode findValue(@JsonProperty("mode") String mode, @JsonProperty("code") String code) {
        return Arrays.stream(PinOperationMode.values()).filter(pt -> pt.mode.equals(mode) && pt.code.equals(code)).findFirst().get();
    }

Comment: @Stefan Hi, I haven't tested it with other setups because the question was about only one field and said nothing about `@JsonFormat`. It's good to know that you made it work for more fields, though. Cheers!

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner no problem, i posted the answer for this case below. cheers

Comment: is there any way, with jackson, to do this with a plain old string instead of a json string? i.e. if the input to say a restful endpoint is a request header with a string value of `ready` not `"ready"`. Is there any way for jackson to recognize `ready` as a string literal value to be passed to  `fromString` instead of requiring it be a json string like `"ready"`?

Comment: @Achilles929 I don't know if there's some config flag to render JSON strings as invalid json strings, i.e. without quotes. You can always do some hacking, though, but it would be out of the scope of this question/answer. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164435/jackson-field-value-with-no-quotation-marks

Answer (score 12):

This is probably a faster way to do it:

```
public enum Status {
 READY("ready"),
 NOT_READY("notReady"),
 NOT_READY_AT_ALL("notReadyAtAll");

 private final String formatted;

 Status(String formatted) {
   this.formatted = formatted;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
   return formatted;
 }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(Status.class);
  Status status = reader.with(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING).readValue("\"notReady\"");
  System.out.println(status.name());  // NOT_READY
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work atleast with versions >=2.8, Accepted answer seems to be much better and it works

Comment: This works for me after spring update from 1.5.X to 2.4.X. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
@JsonCreator
public static Status forValue(String name)
{
    return EnumUtil.getEnumByNameIgnoreCase(Status.class, name);
}
```

Adding this static method would resolve your problem of deserializing

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: solved it for me

Answer (score 6):

For whoever is searching for enums with integer json properties. Here is what worked for me:

```
enum class Status (private val code: Int) {
    PAST(0),
    LIVE(2),
    UPCOMING(1);
    companion object {
        private val codes = Status.values().associateBy(Status::code)
        @JvmStatic @JsonCreator fun from (value: Int) = codes[value]
    }
}
```

Comment: This really helped me! I had the `@JsonCreator` annotation and thought it would be enough, but apparently `@JvmStatic` was required as well.

Comment: This is the best answer for Kotlin I could find.

Answer (score 5):

`@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)` was the solution for me.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/336#issuecomment-630587525

Answer (score 4):

The solutions on this page work only for single field and @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NATURAL) (default format)

this works for multiple fields and @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum PinOperationMode {
    INPUT("Input", "I"),
    OUTPUT("Output", "O")
    ;

    private final String mode;
    private final String code;

    PinOperationMode(String mode, String code) {
        this.mode = mode;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    static PinOperationMode findValue(@JsonProperty("mode") String mode, @JsonProperty("code") String code) {
        return Arrays.stream(PinOperationMode.values()).filter(pt -> pt.mode.equals(mode) && pt.code.equals(code)).findFirst().get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@JsonCreator` annotation to resolve your problem. Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums, there's clear enough explanation about enum and serialize-deserialize with jackson lib.