# RESTful Validate request body JSON and XML format

Tags: java, json, xml, rest

This is my enum class:

```
@XmlType(name = "V4NetworkCIDRType")
@XmlEnum
public enum V4NetworkCIDRType {
    @XmlEnumValue("Y")
    Y("Y"),
    @XmlEnumValue("N")
    N("N");

    private final String value;

    V4NetworkCIDRType(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static V4NetworkCIDRType fromValue(String v) {
        for (V4NetworkCIDRType c: V4NetworkCIDRType.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }
}
```

I have a field with name **cird** and type is V4NetworkCIDRType.
If I set value for **cird** is Y or N, it working correctly. But when I send a request JSON format with wrong **cidr** value:

```
{
    "cidr": "@"
}
```

It will return 400 Bad request

But when I send request with XML format:

```
 <cidr>@</cidr>
```

It's OK.

How I can do that with JSON format?

Comment: What happens if you change that `throw new IllegalArgumentException(v)` to `return N`?

Comment: I have changed it, but it have the same problem. I have debug for fromValue method and it not used.

Comment: I have solved my problem with solution in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689107/deserializing-an-enum-with-jackson)