# How to custom convert String to enum in @RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, enums, jackson

I want to send a JSON request body where fields can be enum values. These enum values are in camelCase, but the enum values are UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.

Kotlin classes:

```
data class CreatePersonDto @JsonCreator constructor (
        @JsonProperty("firstName") val firstName: String,
        @JsonProperty("lastName") val lastName: String,
        @JsonProperty("idType") val idType: IdType
)
```

```
enum class IdType {
    DRIVING_LICENCE,
    ID_CARD,
    PASSPORT;
}
```

My endpoint signature:

```
@PostMapping
fun createPerson(@RequestBody person: CreatePersonDto)
```

HTTP request:

```
curl -d '{ "firstName": "King", "lastName": "Leonidas", "idType": "drivingLicence" }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/person
```

I want to convert "drivingLicence" to DRIVING_LICENCE implicitly.

## **I have tried:**

- `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`: It works for `@RequestParam`, but not for `@RequestBody`
- `org.springframework.format.Formatter`: I registered this formatter, but when I make the request the `parse()` method is not executed.

My configuration so far:

```
@Configuration
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {

    override fun addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry) {
        registry.addConverter(IdTypeConverter())
        registry.addFormatter(IdTypeFormatter())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to use `JsonProperty` on enum directly

```
enum IdType {

    @JsonProperty("drivingLicence")
    DRIVING_LICENCE,

    @JsonProperty("idCard")
    ID_CARD,

    @JsonProperty("passport")
    PASSPORT;
}
```

If you want to have multimapping the simple thing would be defining mapping and using `JsonCreator` on enum level:

```
enum IdType {

    DRIVING_LICENCE,
    ID_CARD,
    PASSPORT;

    private static Map<String, IdType> mapping = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        mapping.put("drivingLicence", DRIVING_LICENCE);
        mapping.put(DRIVING_LICENCE.name(), DRIVING_LICENCE);
        // ...
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static IdType fromString(String value) {
        return mapping.get(value);
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Deserializing an enum with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689107/deserializing-an-enum-with-jackson)

Comment: What could be the solution if I want to permit "drivingLicence" and "DRIVING_LICENCE" as valid arguments as well?