# "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of" error even though constructor exists

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-value

I have this Java enum:

```
public enum UserTypeEnum implements EnumConverter {
USER(1),
USERS_GROUP(2);

private final int type;

UserTypeEnum(int type) {
    this.type= type;
}

@Override
@JsonValue
public int getType() {
    return type;
}
}
```

With the simple interface:

```
public interface EnumConverter {
int getType();
}
```

I put the @JsonValue annotation above the getType method as I wanted these objects to appear in the JSON as integers. The problem is that when Jackson tries to deserialize them, I get:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `UserTypeEnum` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1) at {"type":1}
```

Even though the constructor exists. I want Jackson to use either the constructor or the getType method in deserialization. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689107/deserializing-an-enum-with-jackson answer your question?

Comment: Nope. Tried to add a static method with @JsonCreator annotation but still got the same error..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a method, that will guide Jackson on how to deserialize it from `JSON` to `POJO`.

Try something like this:

```java
@JsonCreator 
    public static UserTypeEnum fromValue(int value) {
        for (UserTypeEnum userType : values()) {
            if (userType.getType() == value) {
                return userType;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type value: " + value);
    }
```

or with Stream API:

```java
@JsonCreator
public static UserTypeEnum fromValue(int value) {
    return Arrays.stream(UserTypeEnum.values())
                 .filter(userType -> userType.getType() == value)
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type value: " + value));
}
```

Comment: I added the method: "public static UserTypeEnum getEnum(int type)"  with the @JsonCreator annotation but still got the same error... any idea why?