# JSON data containing function for testing

Tags: javascript, json, console

Wanting to run some tests, how can I achieve the following:

`function(){console.log('console me')}` **within** the data surrounded by text, but I don't want the data displaying in HTML as it currently does, I want it to execute instead, and only for the surrounding text to display on the page.

JSON Data

```
[{ "id": "1", "text": "I am testing console log from within json data function(){console.log('console this text')} so the text before this should not appear in html, rather it should run and all this other text should appear"}]
```

Comment: The JSON isn't the right place to be looking. It's whatever you're using to put things on the page that you should be looking at using to add a function. You can't run functions just by putting them in random string values in a JSON structure. You'd have to have whatever's *consuming* the JSON extract that code snippet and make it get evaluated (it might do that by putting that text within a `script` tag, or calling `eval` on it). You need to step back and look at a different approach altogether.

Comment: You have to build a directive for example because functions are not allowed in JSON. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2001471/1165289

Comment: Ahhh I get exactly what you mean :) How would I build a directive for it though? Just want to test this :) thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it valid to define functions in JSON results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results)