# node.js require of a json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to require() this JSON file.

```
{
    "info" : function (request) {
        var i = "<pre>";
        i+= "current working directory: " + process.cwd() + "\n";
        i+="request url: " + request.url + "\n";
        i+= "</pre>";
        return i;
    }
}
```

Using this line

```
var render = require('./render.json');
```

But I get an exception from the JSON file of : Unexpected token u

What am I doing wrong please ?

The following works in a browser. Which I would expect, since a function is a object.
And nodejs docs suggests JSON can be a module: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script>

  var a = {
    "b" : function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    }
  }

  a.b("Hello");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the JSON file?

Comment: is there a line number given (in the CSV)?

Comment: unexpected token "u" is because the only valid token after "f" is "a" (for "false")

Comment: That makes perfect sense @andrey-sidorov. I am new to nodejs, so maybe modules are not what I think they are.

Comment: You're trying to mix JSON and JS here.  The two languages are actually distinct from one another, despite sharing very similar syntax.  JSON is basically the specific subset of JS syntax that allows you to define certain data structures - strings, booleans, numbers, Objects, and Arrays.  Note that functions are *not* part of this!  JS, on the other hand is... well.. everything else.  Your `render.json` file isn't valid JSON *or* JS.  Thus, there's no way to interpret it that makes sense in either context!  tl;dr - functions aren't valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have gotten around this is to create a js file instead of a json file:
config.js

```
exports.config = [
    {
        "foo": 12,
        "bar": 10,
        "baz": function(a){
            console.dir(a);
        }
    }
]
```

then within node:

```
 config = require('./config.js').config;

 var a = {
   m: 'something',
   o: 'somethingelses'
 }

 config[0].baz(a);
```

Answer (score 4):

JSON is purely meant to be a data description language. Per http://www.json.org, it is a "lightweight data-interchange format." - not a programming language.

you cannot have function inside your JSON and use node.

```
{
    "error": [
        function (request) {

        }
    ]

}
```

[Is it valid to define functions in JSON results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results)