# How to load a Highcharts options object, including a callback property, with getJSON

Tags: json, highcharts

I'm currently loading and rendering Highcharts by making a jquery getJSON call to a web service, like so:

```
$.getJSON('options.json')
    .done(function (chartOptions) {
            $('#chartholder').highcharts(chartOptions);
    });
```

This all works fine until I have to use an option that requires a javascript callback, such as [axis label formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter). When I try it fails with an Uncaught TypeError exception and states the Object has no method 'call'.

I suspect this is as a result of the json, returned by the web service, wrapping the formatter property in quotes so it is valid json, but Highcharts expecting it to be a callback.

Is there a way to return a callback method in the json and for Highcharts to recognise it as such?

Comment: In JSON you can't pass functions. You can pass string and then eval to function. See also [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to  move you json options to script (come options.js). For example:

```
//options.js example
window.chartConfig = {
 charType: 'spline',
 tickPositioner: function() {console.log('bla-bla')}
}

// in some main script
$.getScript('options.js')
    .done(function () {
            window
            $('#chartholder').highcharts(window.chartConfig);
    });
```