# chrome.runtime.sendMessage the parameter message, does support function type?

Tags: google-chrome-app, sendmessage

`var msg = {
        name: '',
        type: 'xhr',
        success: function(){},
        args: {

            url: 'exp.com',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(){},
            error: function(){console.log('failed')
        }
    };`

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

i try to make a callback function, like success: function(){}, error(){}, but is does not work, why ?

when i use 
`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log(message)
});`
but can not receive success: function(){}, error:function(){} ?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What exactly are you trying to do? Currently, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: when i use chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener, but can not receive success: function(){}, error:function(){} ? , it only string

Comment: Seems there's a typo in your `msg` line, is that typo in your real code?

Comment: my en is poor just by translator online to express my meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `sendMessage` does not support sending functions. `sendMessage` operates by serializing the object to a JSON string before sending the message. JSON does not support functions ([for several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results)), and any function objects inside the message will be dropped. For example, test out `JSON.stringify({ success: function() {} })`: you get the result `"{}"`, because keys whose values are functions get dropped.

Instead, you'll either need to:

1. Pass some function parameters in the message and have the receiver build a new function. For example, pass `success: { action: "display", header: "Here are your results..." }` and then have the receiver use those parameters to build a new function that performs the `display` action with the given `header` value.
2. Turn the function into a string before transmission, and then `eval` the function string to rebuild the function upon receipt. This is a bit of a nasty hack, and will drop any outer scope the function previously had access to, but it will work. Note that you'll need to wrap the function expression in parentheses to have `eval` parse it:

   ```
   eval( "(" + functionString + ")" );
   ```