# Traversing between parent / child properties in nested JSON objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object and a property of which is a nested json. The nested json has a function as a property. I want to access a property in that outer json from that function in that inner json.

Let me explain with a dummy code,

```
{
  name: "Barry Allen",
  getName: function () { 
      return this.name; //this is returning "Barry Allen", which is fine
    },
  nestedJson: {
    getName: function () {
      //here I want something like return this.parent.name
    }
   }  
}
```

I want to access `name` from `getName` of `nestedJson`. Is it possible? Is there any parent child traversing mechanism/way in json and nested json objects in javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results

Comment: This is not JSON, JSON doesn't support functions. This is a JavaScript object.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object), not JSON.

The context of `this` inside `nestedJson.getName()` is different than the context of `this` inside the first-level `.getName()`.  Since this object will already be defined by the time this function exists, you can use the object itself as a replacement for `this`.

```
var person = {
   name: "Some Guy",
       getName: function () { 
       return this.name;
   },
   nested: {
       getName: function () {
           return person.name;
       }
   }  
};

var try1 = person.getName();
var try2 = person.nested.getName();

console.log('try1', try1);
console.log('try2', try2);
```

That being said, I'd turn this into a different type of object.  Read this:  http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: Nice Approach. One thing, `this` inside `nested.getName()` should be whatever on the left side of `getName()`, in this case, it is `nested` object, not `window`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mike, Also thanks for the link, I will read it. But changing the object structure is not in my hand. I didn't write it :P