# Why is json_encode() not including functions of the object specified

Tags: php, json, oop

I am trying out `json_encode` for the first time I created an object

```
class Test {
  public $action= 'sleep';

  public function wake() {
    $this->action = 'wake';
  }
}
```

then I encode it

```
$enc_obj = json_encode(new Test());
```

I then var_dump()ed it

```
var_dump($enc_obj);
```

I got a list of the property without the functions

```
'{"action":"sleep"}'
```

Am I missing something or that is how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Yes you are missing the fact that when you serialize an object only the data is serialized, not the code. How is it supposed to serialize something you are supposed to "execute"?

Comment: thank you very much, i didn't think to that direction.

Comment: added relevant tag, fixed grammar, added code formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

json_encode() will only output data in a JSON format. The JSON format does not support any functions, neither javascript nor PHP functions. As noted on http://www.json.org, it is a "lightweight data-interchange format." - not a programming language.

See also [Is it valid to define functions in JSON results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results)

In PHP, you may extend the [jsonSerializeable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface to manually define how the JSON result should be.