# How to parse JSON string to javascript object which have function property?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I know the `JSON.parse()` method that will convert valid json string to Javascript object. But I have the below string that and when I tried to parse that string using `JSON.parse()` it throws an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

```
{ "test" : 
[
    {
        "first_name": "Sammy",
        "last_name" : "Shark",
        "online"    : true,
        "full_name" : function() {
           return this.first_name + " " + this.last_name;
        }
    }
]
```

}

now as you can see the above json string contains the function `full_name()` that is why it throws an error.
Please provide any suggestion to handle this scenario.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: JSON cannot have functions. Only string, number, object, array, booealn and null are allowed https://www.json.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it valid to define functions in JSON results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449)

Comment: @str Is there any other parser available? that can parse this string