# rl_json : Insert function

Tags: json, tcl

below my `json` :

```
  "temperature": {
    "level": 8,
    "format": function (value) {
                            return value + ' (C°)';
                            },
    "minimum": null,
    ...
    ...
    }
```

My goal is to write key `format`, I have try this but without much conviction...

```
package require rl_json
namespace import rl_json::json

set rj "{}"
set s1 {function (value) {
            return value + ' (C°)';
        }
        }


json set rj temperature [json object [list level {number 8} format [json template {{"~L:s1"}}] minimum {null}]]
```

> Error parsing JSON value: Expecting : after object key at offset 8

Comment: JSON can not contain functions. See also: [Is it valid to define functions in JSON results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results)

Comment: @SchelteBron , It is not standard... but in my case I have JSON files that contain functions. Is there a workaround with `rl_json` package ?

Comment: You are trying to create JSON containing a function. That is not valid (or as you call it, standard) JSON. It is not supported by rl_json.

Comment: A workaround could be to insert some special pattern in the JSON string, which you later replace using `string map`. But from that point on, `rl_json` will no longer be able to work with the value.

Comment: @SchelteBron, ok I wanted to avoid using that... but if it's not supported, I will use `string map`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to produce is not (partial) JSON, as [defined](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), but rather general Javascript. As such, you cannot reasonably expect JSON-specific tooling (such as `rl_json`) to work with it. It is *usually* better to keep your JSON and your Javascript separated, with the data in JSON (including any dynamic generation) and your Javascript as a static artefact (or generated from something like Typescript). Mixing code and dynamic generation requires great care to get right; it is usually better to try to write things so you don't need to be that careful!

If you must do this defintely-not-advised thing, use something like `subst` or `format` to inject the variable parts (which you can generate with `rl_json`) in the overall string. No code for that from me: my advice is ***don't do that.***

Comment: ok If I can't how do you do ? `function` or `variable` are not supported with `rl_json` ? If I understand  `subst` , `string map` or `format` is for me the only solution

Comment: You. Can't. Put. Code. In. There. This is difficult because you should not do this. (Put in the name of a function — as a string — to call that is defined elsewhere.)

Comment: Sorry English is not my first language. You’re right`,` punctuation is important to make that clear`.` That said, thanks for your comment`...`