# Can't call a function on an object converted to ref and retrieved from pinia store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I have a Vue3 app with TypeScript and Pinia.

In the _Layout.vue component when I call `currentUser.value.hasPermission()` I get the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: currentUser.value.hasPermission is not a function`.

**Is there something with refs or pinia stores that would prevent me from calling a function on an object that had been stored in them?**

Code below.

```js
// @/stores/main-store.ts

import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import type { IUser } from "@/lib/user";

export const useStore = defineStore({
  id: "main",
  state: () => ({
    currentUser: {} as IUser,
    currentTenant: null as string | null,
    theme: null as string | null,
  }),
});
```

```js
// @/lib/user.ts

import { getToken } from "@/lib/auth";

export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  tenants: IUserTenant[];
  hasPermission: (
    tenantIdentifier: string|null,
    permission: IUserPermission
  ) => boolean;
}

export interface IUserTenant {
  tenantIdentifier: string;
  tenantName: string;
  permissions: IUserPermission[];
}

export interface IUserPermission {
  permissionZone: PermissionZone;
  permissionType: PermissionType;
}

export enum PermissionZone {
  Me,
  Tenants,
  Users,
  Contacts,
}
export enum PermissionType {
  List,
  Read,
  Create,
  Update,
  Delete,
}

const API_EP = import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT;
export class User implements IUser {

  public static async getCurrentUser(): Promise<IUser> {
    const token = await getToken();
    const response = await fetch(`${API_EP}/user`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      mode: "cors",
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      return (await response.json()) as User;
    }

    // TODO Define Error response model and parse for message
    throw new Error("Unable to retrieve current user.");
  }

  public id!: string;
  public tenants: IUserTenant[] = [];
  public hasPermission(tenantIdentifier: string | null, permission: IUserPermission): boolean {
    return this.tenants.some(
      (t) =>
        t.tenantIdentifier === tenantIdentifier &&
        t.permissions.some(
          (p) =>
            p.permissionZone === permission.permissionZone &&
            p.permissionType === permission.permissionType
        )
    );
  }
}
```

```js
// @/views/_Layout.vue - <script> section

import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "@/stores/main-store";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { Navigation } from "@/lib/navigation";
import type { INavigationItem } from "@/lib/navigation";

const store = useStore();
const { currentUser, currentTenant } = storeToRefs(store);

const navItems = ref<INavigationItem[]>();
onMounted(async () => {
  navItems.value = Navigation.filter((i) =>
    currentUser.value.hasPermission(
      currentTenant.value,
      i.permission
    )
  );
});
```

**Edit** I forgot about where the `currentUser` gets populated - this is done in the router setup as follows:

```js
// @/router/index.ts

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Layout from "@/views/_Layout.vue";
import { AuthenticationGuard } from "vue-auth0-plugin";
import { User } from "@/lib/user";
import { useStore } from "@/stores/main-store";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      name: "default",
      path: "/",
      component: Layout,
      beforeEnter: async (to, from) => {
        // Handle login
        const authed = await AuthenticationGuard(to, from);

        useStore().$patch({
          currentUser: await User.getCurrentUser(),
        });

        if (authed && to.name === "default")
          await router.push({ name: "dashboard" });
        return authed;
      },
      children: [
        {
          name: "dashboard",
          path: "",
          component: () => import("@/views/DashboardPage.vue"),
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});

export default router;
```

Comment: BTW, in TypeScript interfaces do not use the capital-i `I` prefix. TypeScript isn't COM nor .NET.

Comment: `currentUser: {} as IUser,` <-- This is incorrect. An empty object does not satisfy your `IUser` type. (Generally speaking you should avoid using `as` in TypeScript

Comment: @Hades You don't use User class anywhere, so you can't expect its methods to exist

Comment: @Dai That's opinionated. A prefix is welcome if you don't want to rely on IDE highlighting distinguishing them or think about how to avoid name collisions (User and IUser). And no, you can't avoid using `as` but this needs to be justified. It cheats TS here.

Comment: @EstusFlask It's not an opinion: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/121

Comment: @Dai The link discusses somebody's opinion on the subject, and you may notice there's no consensus on it, and it's not a part of the official docs. That's the meaning of "opinionated". You don't have to impose it like something obligatory, because it's not. That's just code style, which may be undesirable for the reason I explained above.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for the input. As @EstusFlask mentioned, the use of `I` for interfaces is a personal style choice as I find it makes it much clearer what is an interface.

In terms of the issue at hand, I missed an important piece from the question which I'll update after posting this comment. Namely, that I populate the `currentUser` in the store within the `beforeEnter` in the vue-router setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentUser` is populated from `getCurrentUser()`, which returns the JSON object from a `fetch()`:

```js
// @/lib/user.ts
public static async getCurrentUser(): Promise<IUser> {
  ⋮
  if (response.ok) {
    return (await response.json()) as User;
  }
}
```

`fetch()` returns serializable data objects, [which cannot contain functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2001471/6277151), so I don't believe it's correct to cast the JSON response as `User`.

If I understand the problem correctly, `getCurrentUser()` should actually create an instance of `User` from the JSON response, and return that instance. You could do that by creating a class constructor that receives the JSON response, and copies over the data into its fields.

Comment: That was it! I'm from a C# background so had assumed that casting to a class would force it to include the functions defined in the class... guess not.