# Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom, eval, innerhtml

I've got a script that inserts some content into an element using `innerHTML`.

The content could for example be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('test');</script>
<strong>test</strong>
```

Problem is that the code inside the `<script>` tag doesn't get executed.
I googled it a bit but there were no apparent solutions. If I inserted the content using jQuery `$(element).append(content);`the script parts got `eval`'d before being injected into the DOM.

Has anyone got a snippet of code that executes all the `<script>` elements? The jQuery code was a bit complex so I couldn't really figure out how it was done.

**Edit**:

By peeking into the jQuery code I've managed to figure out how jQuery does it, which resulted in the following code:

```
Demo:
<div id="element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function insertAndExecute(id, text)
  {
    domelement = document.getElementById(id);
    domelement.innerHTML = text;
    var scripts = [];

    ret = domelement.childNodes;
    for ( var i = 0; ret[i]; i++ ) {
      if ( scripts && nodeName( ret[i], "script" ) && (!ret[i].type || ret[i].type.toLowerCase() === "text/javascript") ) {
            scripts.push( ret[i].parentNode ? ret[i].parentNode.removeChild( ret[i] ) : ret[i] );
        }
    }

    for(script in scripts)
    {
      evalScript(scripts[script]);
    }
  }
  function nodeName( elem, name ) {
    return elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toUpperCase() === name.toUpperCase();
  }
  function evalScript( elem ) {
    data = ( elem.text || elem.textContent || elem.innerHTML || "" );

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement,
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.appendChild( document.createTextNode( data ) );
    head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );
    head.removeChild( script );

    if ( elem.parentNode ) {
        elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem );
    }
  }

  insertAndExecute("element", "<scri"+"pt type='text/javascript'>document.write('This text should appear as well.')</scr"+"ipt><strong>this text should also be inserted.</strong>");
</script>
```

Comment: Have your tried adding content (JS as innerHTML of DOM Node) and then calling the function(s) added? For example if you append Javascript containing a function FOO(){ } you can try calling function later.

Comment: I don't think that you can have execution upon insertion in the DOM.

Comment: Why can't you just iterate the children of the element, and for each one that is a script element you just eval() the innerHtml of that child? This is how i've seen it done by a large component vendor, every time they complete an ajax callback that adds stuff to the DOM they do exactly that. Bear in mind though that it can be slow, especially in IE7.

Comment: Andreas: If I add a function, for example `function testFunction(){ alert('test'); }` to the code inserted into innerHTML, and then try calling it, it says that the function is not defined.

Comment: I think it is absolutely important to understand that this is intended behaviour by the browser to prevent Cross-site scripting attacks. If the text you set as innerHTML is provided by Bob it would execute on Alice's browser causing damage (think of a forum where people can write comments adding script-tags to them). You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting. Stay save!

Comment: Because the node has already loaded.  Can't you just put the deferred attribute on your script tag?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The OP's script doesn't work in IE 7. With help from SO, here's a script that does:

```
exec_body_scripts: function(body_el) {
  // Finds and executes scripts in a newly added element's body.
  // Needed since innerHTML does not run scripts.
  //
  // Argument body_el is an element in the dom.

  function nodeName(elem, name) {
    return elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toUpperCase() ===
              name.toUpperCase();
  };

  function evalScript(elem) {
    var data = (elem.text || elem.textContent || elem.innerHTML || "" ),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
                  document.documentElement,
        script = document.createElement("script");

    script.type = "text/javascript";
    try {
      // doesn't work on ie...
      script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));      
    } catch(e) {
      // IE has funky script nodes
      script.text = data;
    }

    head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
    head.removeChild(script);
  };

  // main section of function
  var scripts = [],
      script,
      children_nodes = body_el.childNodes,
      child,
      i;

  for (i = 0; children_nodes[i]; i++) {
    child = children_nodes[i];
    if (nodeName(child, "script" ) &&
      (!child.type || child.type.toLowerCase() === "text/javascript")) {
          scripts.push(child);
      }
  }

  for (i = 0; scripts[i]; i++) {
    script = scripts[i];
    if (script.parentNode) {script.parentNode.removeChild(script);}
    evalScript(scripts[i]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Better use jQuery's `$(parent).html(code)` - see my answer below.

Comment: once script is injected to DOM, how should I remove it?

Comment: The script isn't recursive, so will only look at direct children.
This works for me:
`if (nodeName(child, "script" ) &&
  (!child.type || child.type.toLowerCase() === "text/javascript")) {
      scripts.push(child);
  } else {
    exec_body_scripts(child);
  }`

Comment: Note that the above code doesn't execute scripts that load via src. The above script can be changed to check `elem.src` and conditionally set the `src` property of the created script element instead of setting its text content.

Comment: Why not to use [the global `eval` trick](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2) instead of creating a `<script>` element and inserting it to the `<head>`? They both execute JS code without exposing the current closure.

Answer (score 120):

Simplified ES6 version of @joshcomley's answer with an example.

No JQuery, No library, No eval, No DOM change, Just pure Javascript.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MMegiu?p=preview

```
function setInnerHTML(elm, html) {
  elm.innerHTML = html;
  
  Array.from(elm.querySelectorAll("script"))
    .forEach( oldScriptEl => {
      const newScriptEl = document.createElement("script");
      
      Array.from(oldScriptEl.attributes).forEach( attr => {
        newScriptEl.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value) 
      });
      
      const scriptText = document.createTextNode(oldScriptEl.innerHTML);
      newScriptEl.appendChild(scriptText);
      
      oldScriptEl.parentNode.replaceChild(newScriptEl, oldScriptEl);
  });
}
```

Usage

```
$0.innerHTML = HTML;    // does *NOT* run <script> tags in HTML
setInnerHTML($0, HTML); // does run <script> tags in HTML
```

Comment: Working example http://plnkr.co/edit/b54rQgoSkguOFpIJ

Answer (score 43):

Here is a very interesting solution to your problem:
http://24ways.org/2005/have-your-dom-and-script-it-too

So it would look like this instead:

```
<img src="empty.gif" onload="alert('test');this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />
```

Comment: and even better, no need to have an image with "onerror" event, nice for quick XSS injection http://www.jvfconsulting.com/blog/47/Beware_Of_The_onerror_Attribute_On_IMG_HTML_Tags.html :)

Comment: You can use `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" onload="alert('test');">` if you want to prevent a useless http request.

Comment: love it !  (added `style="display:none;`) to hide the broken image icon

Comment: Actually, `<style>` is better than `<img>`, because it does not make a network request

Comment: Yep, @basin is correct. I used `<style onload="alert('test');"/>` and it worked like a charm. No network request, minimal increase in document/request size, invisible... If you still want to remove it, you can also use the removeChild trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

You should not use the innerHTML property but rather the appendChild method of the Node: a node in a document tree  [HTML DOM]. This way you are able to later call your injected code.

Make sure that you understand that `node.innerHTML` *is not the same as* `node.appendChild`. You might want to spend some time on the Javascript Client Reference for more details and the DOM.  Hope the following helps...

Sample injection works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function doOnLoad() {
            addScript('inject',"function foo(){ alert('injected'); }");
        }
    
        function addScript(inject,code) {
            var _in = document.getElementById('inject');
            var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
            scriptNode.innerHTML = code;
            _in.appendChild(scriptNode);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="doOnLoad();">
    <div id="header">some content</div>
    <div id="inject"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="foo(); return false;" value="Test Injected" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 24):

Here's a shorter, more efficient script that also works for scripts with the `src` property:

```js
function insertAndExecute(id, text) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
    var scripts = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("script"));
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        if (scripts[i].src != "") {
            var tag = document.createElement("script");
            tag.src = scripts[i].src;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
        }
        else {
            eval(scripts[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: whilst `eval` may cause a security vulnerability if not used properly, it is **much** faster than creating a script tag on the fly.

Comment: this helped me but i feel dirty using eval. making sure text cannot be compromised i don't see a vulnerability.

Comment: @random-user `eval` was designed to hurt users. Any dynamic script execution is a risk and this is why CSP calls it `'unsafe-eval'` because it is. You are also hurting the security of your sites if you are using it in a library as they can't turn it off.

Comment: Testing this in Chrome 44 causes an infinite loop when appendChild is called since this increments the scripts.length value.

Comment: Scripts with the `src` property will be downloaded asynchronously
and executed as arrived. Ordering is not preserved. Inline scripts
will also be executed out-of-order, synchronously before the async ones.

Comment: newer invocation: `[...document.querySelectorAll(\`#${id} script\`)].forEach(script => {  if (scripts.src != "") { ... }})`

Answer (score 18):

Try this snippet:

```
function stripAndExecuteScript(text) {
    var scripts = '';
    var cleaned = text.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(){
        scripts += arguments[1] + '\n';
        return '';
    });

    if (window.execScript){
        window.execScript(scripts);
    } else {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        scriptElement.innerText = scripts;
        head.appendChild(scriptElement);
        head.removeChild(scriptElement);
    }
    return cleaned;
};


var scriptString = '<scrip' + 't + type="text/javascript">alert(\'test\');</scr' + 'ipt><strong>test</strong>';
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = stripAndExecuteScript(scriptString);
```

Comment: yeah this method works but you'll get errors if you have comments or console.logs so watch out for that also you can modify to account for modules var modules = []
  var cleaned = text.replace(/<script([^>]*)>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(m, tags, script){
    if (/type="module"/.test(tags)) {
      modules.push(script)
      return
    }
    scripts += script + '\n'
    return ''
  })

Answer (score 18):

```
function insertHtml(id, html)  
{  
   var ele = document.getElementById(id);  
   ele.innerHTML = html;  
   var codes = ele.getElementsByTagName("script");   
   for(var i=0;i<codes.length;i++)  
   {  
       eval(codes[i].text);  
   }  
}
```

It works in Chrome in my project

Answer (score 11):

A solution without using "eval":

```
var setInnerHtml = function(elm, html) {
  elm.innerHTML = html;
  var scripts = elm.getElementsByTagName("script");
  // If we don't clone the results then "scripts"
  // will actually update live as we insert the new
  // tags, and we'll get caught in an endless loop
  var scriptsClone = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    scriptsClone.push(scripts[i]);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < scriptsClone.length; i++) {
    var currentScript = scriptsClone[i];
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    // Copy all the attributes from the original script
    for (var j = 0; j < currentScript.attributes.length; j++) {
      var a = currentScript.attributes[j];
      s.setAttribute(a.name, a.value);
    }
    s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(currentScript.innerHTML));
    currentScript.parentNode.replaceChild(s, currentScript);
  }
}
```

This essentially clones the script tag and then replaces the blocked script tag with the newly generated one, thus allowing execution.

Answer (score 4):

Using the short and sweet approach from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62641523/3394495 :

It first parses the HTML to a `DocumentFragement` (using [createContextualFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) which is supported in all modern browsers, yet marked experimental) and then adds that to the DOM.

This will execute inline scripts.

```
export function setInnerHTMLAndExecuteScripts(element: HTMLElement, html: string) {
    const newContent = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html);
    element.innerHTML = '';
    element.append(newContent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cheshire , it work ! I don't know what does the `createRange` the MDN doc is obscure...

Answer (score 3):

`scriptNode.innerHTML = code` didn't work for IE. The only thing to do is replace with `scriptNode.text = code` and it work fine

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to use jquery `$(parent).html(code)` instead of `parent.innerHTML = code`:

```
var oldDocumentWrite = document.write;
var oldDocumentWriteln = document.writeln;
try {
    document.write = function(code) {
        $(parent).append(code);
    }
    document.writeln = function(code) {
        document.write(code + "<br/>");
    }
    $(parent).html(html); 
} finally {
    $(window).load(function() {
        document.write = oldDocumentWrite
        document.writeln = oldDocumentWriteln
    })
}
```

This also works with scripts that use `document.write` and scripts loaded via `src` attribute. Unfortunately even this doesn't work with Google AdSense scripts.

Comment: What makes you say that it is easier? It’s not even shorter. I always think that overusing jQuery is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works for me on Chrome, Safari & Firefox:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = 'console.log("hi")';
document.body.appendChild(script); 
--> logs "hi"
```

One thing to note though, is that the following div-nested script will NOT run:

```
var script = document.createElement('div');
script.innerHTML = '<script>console.log("hi")</script>';
document.body.appendChild(script);
--> doesn't log anything
```

For a script to run it has to be created as a node then appended as a child. You can even append a script inside a previously injected div & it will run (I've run into this before when trying to get ad server code to work):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'test-id';
document.body.appendChild(div);
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = 'console.log("hi")';
document.getElementById('test-id').appendChild(script);
--> logs "hi"
```

Answer (score 3):

Execute script element by normal .innerHTML just don't put "" start and closing tags in .innerhtml value. Have a look on my code, it's just simple as normal code no jQuery or any other long JavaScript function

```html
<h2>Click on Run to execute script</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="run()">Run</button>
<script id="my_script"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById("my_script").innerHTML= "function run(){alert('Wow! Script executed :)');}";

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending off of Larry's.  I made it recursively search the entire block and children nodes.
The script now will also call external scripts that are specified with src parameter.
Scripts are appended to the head instead of inserted and placed in the order they are found. So specifically order scripts are preserved.  And each script is executed synchronously similar to how the browser handles the initial DOM loading.  So if you have a script block that calls jQuery from a CDN and than the next script node uses jQuery... No prob!  Oh and I tagged the appended scripts with a serialized id based off of what you set in the tag parameter so you can find what was added by this script.

```
exec_body_scripts: function(body_el, tag) {
    // Finds and executes scripts in a newly added element's body.
    // Needed since innerHTML does not run scripts.
    //
    // Argument body_el is an element in the dom.

    function nodeName(elem, name) {
        return elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toUpperCase() ===
              name.toUpperCase();
    };

    function evalScript(elem, id, callback) {
        var data = (elem.text || elem.textContent || elem.innerHTML || "" ),
            head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
                      document.documentElement;

        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        if (id != '') {
            script.setAttribute('id', id);
        }

        if (elem.src != '') {
            script.src = elem.src;
            head.appendChild(script);
            // Then bind the event to the callback function.
            // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
            script.onreadystatechange = callback;
            script.onload = callback;
        } else {
            try {
                // doesn't work on ie...
                script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));      
            } catch(e) {
                // IE has funky script nodes
                script.text = data;
            }
            head.appendChild(script);
            callback();
        }
    };

    function walk_children(node) {
        var scripts = [],
          script,
          children_nodes = node.childNodes,
          child,
          i;

        if (children_nodes === undefined) return;

        for (i = 0; i<children_nodes.length; i++) {
            child = children_nodes[i];
            if (nodeName(child, "script" ) &&
                (!child.type || child.type.toLowerCase() === "text/javascript")) {
                scripts.push(child);
            } else {
                var new_scripts = walk_children(child);
                for(j=0; j<new_scripts.length; j++) {
                    scripts.push(new_scripts[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        return scripts;
    }

    var i = 0;
    function execute_script(i) {
        script = scripts[i];
        if (script.parentNode) {script.parentNode.removeChild(script);}
        evalScript(scripts[i], tag+"_"+i, function() {
            if (i < scripts.length-1) {
                execute_script(++i);
            }                
        });
    }

    // main section of function
    if (tag === undefined) tag = 'tmp';

    var scripts = walk_children(body_el);

    execute_script(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + '<img src="../images/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="alert(\'test\');this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />';
```

Comment: look like a genius idea

Answer (score 1):

Made this new helper function in TypeScript, maybe someone will appreciate it. If you remove type declaration from script parameter it will just be plain JS.

```js
const evalPageScripts = () => {
  const scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script');

  scripts.forEach((script: HTMLScriptElement) => {
    const newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = script.src;

    if (script.parentNode) {
      script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
    }

    return document.body.appendChild(newScript);
  })
};

export default evalPageScripts;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [this post](http://poeticcode.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/innerhtml-and-script-tags/). The code might look like this:

```
var actualDivToBeUpdated = document.getElementById('test');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("test");<\/script>';
var children = div.childNodes;
actualDivToBeUpdated.innerHTML = '';
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    actualDivToBeUpdated.appendChild(children[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Larry's script, which worked perfectly well in IE10, this is what I've used:

```
$('#' + id)[0].innerHTML = result;
$('#' + id + " script").each(function() { this.text = this.text || $(this).text();} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in a recent project.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="hello_world">Sample</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var div = document.createElement("div");
  var t = document.createElement('template');
  t.innerHTML =  "Check Console tab for javascript output: Hello world!!!<br/><script type='text/javascript' >console.log('Hello world!!!');<\/script>";
  
  for (var i=0; i < t.content.childNodes.length; i++){
    var node = document.importNode(t.content.childNodes[i], true);
    div.appendChild(node);
  }
 document.body.appendChild(div);
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expending the answer of [Lambder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181546/1919821)

> `document.body.innerHTML = '<img src="../images/loaded.gif" alt="" > onload="alert(\'test\');this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />'`;

You can use base64 image to create and load your script

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMjHxIGmVAAAADUlEQVQYV2P4//8/AwAI/AL+iF8G4AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
    onload="var script = document.createElement('script');  script.src = './yourCustomScript.js'; parentElement.append(script);" />
```

Or if you have a `Iframe` you can use it instead

```
<iframe src='//your-orginal-page.com' style='width:100%;height:100%'
    onload="var script = document.createElement('script');  script.src = './your-coustom-script.js'; parentElement.append(script);"
    frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar, but needed the script to remain or be re-created in the same spot as the original script, since my script targets the location of the script tag in the DOM to create/target elements. I also made the script recursive to make sure it also works if it is more than one level down.

NOTE: I use `const` here, if you have a older browser, just use `var`.

```
    window.exec_body_scripts = function(body_el) {
        // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml based on Larry K's answer
        // Finds and executes scripts in a newly added element's body.
        // Needed since innerHTML does not run scripts.
        //
        // Argument body_el is an element in the dom.
        const
            type__Js = 'text/javascript',
            tagName__Script = 'script',
            tagName__Script__Upper = tagName__Script.toUpperCase();
        var scripts = [], script, i;
        function evalScript(elem) {
            var parent = elem.parentNode,
                data = (elem.text || elem.textContent || elem.innerHTML || ""),
                script = document.createElement(tagName__Script);

            script.type = type__Js;
            try {
                // doesn't work on ie...
                script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
            } catch (e) {
                // IE has funky script nodes
                script.text = data;
            }
            // Make sure to re-insert the script at the same position
            // to make sure scripts that target their position
            // in the DOM function as expected.
            var parent = elem.parentNode;
            parent.insertBefore(script, elem);
            parent.removeChild(elem);
        };
        // Get all scripts (recursive)
        if (typeof (document.querySelectorAll) !== typeof (void 0)) {
            document.querySelectorAll('script').forEach((scr) => { if (!scr.type || scr.type.toLowerCase() === type__Js) scripts.push(scr); });
        }
        else {
            var children_nodes = body_el.childNodes, child;
            for (i = 0; children_nodes[i]; i++) {
                child = children_nodes[i];
                if (
                    child.nodeName
                    &&
                    child.nodeName.toUpperCase() === tagName__Script__Upper
                    &&
                    (
                        !child.type
                        ||
                        child.type.toLowerCase() === type__Js
                    )
                ) {
                    scripts.push(child);
                }
                // Recursive call
                window.exec_body_scripts(child);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; scripts[i]; i++) {
            evalScript(scripts[i]);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also pages that needed to execute javascript code (with eval) after the javascript files are loaded so did put load events on the script createelement so when the javascript file(s) were loaded gets executed. My website is a MVC SPA application. It loads partial pages with ajax. Those partial pages are set with innerhtml and then the javascript files are loaded and the javascript code on thst partial page.

Answer (score 0):

I just used appendChild with my script in the element like this :

```
element.innerHTML = response
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '/Scripts/meScript.js';
element.appendChild(script);
```

And it starts to work as expected!

Answer (score -1):

Try function eval().

```
data.newScript = '<script type="text/javascript">//my script...</script>'
var element = document.getElementById('elementToRefresh');
element.innerHTML = data.newScript;
eval(element.firstChild.innerHTML);
```

This is a real example from a project that i am developing.
Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939343/2835520)