# Will scripts inserted with innerHTML never be executed?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am using kind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml) solution to execute `<script>` that is inserted via `innerHTML`, but I need to make sure, those scripts are executed only once. So my question is:

Can I be sure that scripts will not be executed when inserted via innerHTML and why?

EDIT: I need a solution where I can put scripts into a div, that will not be executed when inserted. I want to parse these scripts and execute them by another code snippet. I have a solution that is using innerHTML to insert script-tags into a div and it is working good.

What would be the appropiate way to insert scripts into a div **without** having them executed when inserted?

Comment: Avoiding innerHTML solves your problems. innerHTML is a confusing and wrong tool.

Comment: That depends on the situation. It perfectly OK to use `innerHTML` for static contents. Inserting `<script>` tags with `innerHTML` is very bad though.

Comment: Thanks guys, but that does not answer my question at all... please check my EDIT on the question

Comment: Ah, check out my edited answer. I did even actually kind of answer to your problem before.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert the same script multiple times, it will be executed the corresponding number of times. The DOM parser in the browser executes any `<script>` element (unless its `type` is not `text/javascript`) it encounters.

EDIT: Use a different `type` than `text/javascript`—for instance `type="text/custom"`. The parser only executes `text/javascript`.

Comment: I cannot edit the javascripts that are being inserted - I'll have to use them as they are. From my experience, scripts that are inserted via innerHTML don't get executed upon insertion, for me this is perfect and as far as I tested it works across all common browers. I want to know if this reliably not working, so I can build my logic on this...