# XMLHttpRequest not loading the page properly

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I stumbled upon a strange behaviour of the XMLHttpRequest. Maybe I'm just not well informed enough about its possibilities or possible how Javascript pages load, so could someone please confirm my question?

When I put plain Javascript in a file that is read-in through a XMLHttpRequest-object, it's like it is totally ignored. Eg. I have the file ajax_include.html with in it's body the following lines

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert('some alert');
</script>
```

I also tried it with an external javascript file.

When I directly surf to the file, the alert pops up as expected, but when I use a simple XMLHttpRequest to replace the contents of a div with the contents of this page, the alert is not popping up.

Can someone confirm this strange behaviour? Or is it just normal with the use of an XMLHttpRequest object?

Comment: *How* are you replacing the contents of the div?

Comment: what do you mean by ignored? if you alert() the XMLHttpRequest response it comes empty?

Comment: I dont alert the XMLHttpRequest. The request is supposed to respond with  a page that says "some alert" when it completes. This however is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with XMLHttpRequest. `<script>` elements added to a page with `innerHTML` won't be executed.

See [Executing  elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml) for work arounds.

Comment: If it's any help, for a fact they will execute using jquery's .html().

Comment: Thanks Quentin and goldilocks for the advice and refrence, I will try that