# YQL removes data within <script></script> tags from the requested page

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

I have code seperated in two domain. Both domains and code is trusted.

I wanted to access code of domain B VIA jquery's .load() method from domain A, but came to know that its not possible due to restriction of data-access between cross-domains.

YQL came as option to me, worked fine. BUT it doesn't brings the data in < script >< / script > tags. I have examined the data being returned and it has all the HTML of called page from Domain B otherthan SCRIPT code.

I need to bring SCRIPT code and execute it.

Couldn't find anything related in YQL help (they only mentioned how to remove < script > from returned data), but in my case YQL itself removes scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening at [the url you've provided](http://tele.xtream-dev.com/test.php), is not so much that `script` tags are being stripped, as the YQL select returning only the body of the document by default, and your script is placed in the head.

You can get the head with a query such as this one:

```
where url="..." and xpath='/html/head/'
```

Comment: **A related quick question:** Does YQL strips empty tags? like removes <div class='sep'></div>? as i am not getting any empty divs, which i am using for CSS purpose in my code.

Answer (score 1):

YQL does not strip `<script>` elements. `load()` uses [`innerHTML` which doesn't cause `<script>` elements to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!
In my case YQL is stripping my < script >, have give up .load(). But the problem is that i don't get script from the page being called.

Comment: @KhaledJaveed — The first example of using YQL as a proxy I found — http://bit.ly/KAOFko — does not strip script elements.

Comment: Can you please share the YQL String?

Comment: @KhaledJaveed — Since I copy/pasted it instead of constructing it from scratch: Only if I spent time extracting it from the URI, which you can do yourself.

Comment: @KhaledJaveed: I think the crucial thing to note is that there's no *do-not-strip-script* flag in the query. It might be more constructive if you show *your* YQL String. Are you sure that the script you're looking for is present when the page is loading, rather than added at a later point, at the targeted site?

Comment: @DavidHedlund Please visit the [the link](http://tele.xtream-dev.com/test.php).
This page is calling itself in a div. Please view source of page for details.

Its stripping two divs and script code as well. Cant figure out why..