# JS code within html returned via ajax not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For instance say I run an ajax call and the returned data is something like:

```
<article>
    <h2>Howdy</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('hi');
        posts[23] = 'this wont get added into the posts array';
    </script>
</article>
```

I then insert this returned data straight into a div already on the page. None of the javascript will execute. How do I do this correctly and make it work?
I don't have much control of what gets returned so returning json isn't an option.

Thanks!

Comment: If you aren't in control, _who is?_ Because this is downright weird as an AJAX response and not very useful. I would complain and demand JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute the JS code that was inserted into your html you can use the eval() function. For example: `eval(document.getElementById('myJSDiv').innerHTML);` Hope that's what you're looking for.