# How to insert html content in body part using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert string inside body part of my html document using javascipt. The string which i want to insert contains some script tags also. For example :

```
  var str = "<div> some text </div>
             <script src='/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
```

Now when i insert the above string using jquery , like :

```
 $('body').html(str);
```

It will insert the string and load the jquery also. But when i insert this string using javascript, like :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = str;
```

This will not load the jquery script in the browser. Can anyone tell me how can i achieve the same using javascript ?

Comment: It should work as expected, what if you try the old way of inserting elements in HTML?  @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS yes it is..

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/ here you have a good guide.
So in your case you can try this:

```
  var head= document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var script= document.createElement('script');
  script.type= 'text/javascript';
  script.src= '/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js';
  head.appendChild(script)
```

Comment: assuming /scripts is a dir on the server the page is on, if not, fully qualify it

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that if you are inserting scripts with innerHTML, the scripts will not be executed. No browser will do this because of security issues. jquery implemented a way around this. You can find further information and a solution in pure javascript here: [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)