# Assigning the value of "<script src=" directly to another element

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to assign a value of `<script src="http://domain.com/external.php"></script>` directly to another variable, like the following (not using JQuery, but simple Javascript):

```
<script>

document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML=<script src="http://domain.com/external.php"></script>;

</script>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.... Use strings...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Answer (score 2):

maybe doing something like this is better

```
script=document.createElement('script');
script.src='http://whatever.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I assign it to: document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML
?

Comment: why do you need to assign it to this certain element? scripts should be in the head..

Comment: Because the script outputs some text (and this text should be placed in the body). So I need a way to assign it to a variable, for example:

<div id="ID"></div>

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to append the script inside the DOM **as a string**, you have to do something like this :

```
var script = '<script src="http://domain.com/external.php"></scr'+'ipt>';
document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML = script;
```

the closing script tag will cause issues in parsing when inserted as a string because it closes the current script, concatenation will solve that.