# Write script tag to body (or head if possible)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an image viewer in HTML5 and I want to write a script tag to the body or head but it won't work. Here is an extract from the main script:

```
function play() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("play")[0].setAttribute("class", "play active");
    document.getElementsByClassName("pause")[0].setAttribute("class", "pause");
    var body = document.body.innerHTML;
    body.innerHTML=body + "<script id='playpause' src='res/playpause.js'></script>";
}
```

Here is the script I'm trying to write:

```
var slideshow = setInterval("forward();",5000);

function pause() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("play")[0].setAttribute("class", "play");
    document.getElementsByClassName("pause")[0].setAttribute("class", "pause active");
    window.clearInterval(slideshow);
    var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
    playpause.parentNode.removeChild(playpause);
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image viewer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/style.css" />
        <script src="res/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="play()">
        <div class="img">
            <img title="Hover over me to un-darken" alt="Error displaying image" src="images/1.jpg" id="img" data-number="1" />
        </div>
        <div title="Backward" class="backward" onclick="backward()"></div>
        <div title="Forward" class="forward" onclick="forward()"></div>
        <div title="Play" class="play active" onclick="play()"></div>
        <div title="Pause" class="pause" onclick="pause()"></div>
        <div title="Go to beginning" class="stop" onclick="stop()"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: Using the onload event in the body element is not very reliable.  Are you not interested in libraries like jQuery that have solved these onload problems in a comprehensive way?

Comment: I'm also worried that every time play() is called, you're replacing the body innerHTML with itself and adding the same script element every time.  I have had problems before when I include the same external script multiple times.

Comment: @DavidHyogo I don't really want to use JQuery because it'll just add unnecessary things I don't need. Anything done in JQuery can be done with vanilla JS, just not with simple pre-made functions - all it does is to make it more simple and easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
s.setAttribute("src", "res/playpause.js");
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Can't you do head and body with `document.head`?

Comment: Works, thanks! Modified slightly:  var script = document.createElement("script");
 script.setAttribute("src", "res/playpause.js");
 script.setAttribute("id", "playpause");
 var head = document.head;
 head.appendChild(script);