# XMLHttpRequest -> PHP -> Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

When I call a PHP file using,

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'file.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','*/*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
};
```

the responseText doesn't include jQuery.ajax call in file.php.  However when I do this same thing using

```
jQuery.ajax{( 
url: 'file.php', 
type: 'post',
success: function (data) { jQuery('#container').html(data); }
)};
```

The data includes jQuery.ajax call in file.php.

I am trying to figure out why XMLHttpRequest won't do this for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: This has nothing to do with XMLHttpRequest. It is all about `innerHTML`

Comment: @Quentin You were right, I replaced innerHTML with jQuery.html and it worked fine.  Thanks for the suggestion.