# Is an XSS attack possible when a script is displayed in an HTML textarea?

Tags: java, security, web-applications, browser, xss

I have an HTML textarea in my UI (for a Java-based web app) where a user can enter any value. Once it is saved, it is displayed in the textarea (which is disabled) in the browser.

If a user enters any script as free text in the textarea, will it be executed as a script (even if the value is shown in the textarea, and not not as label/text)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on how you set the value of the `textarea`. In the HTML code, the content of the `textarea` is the text inside the element.

I've created a [JSFiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/5aFP3/) various ways to change the content of a `textarea`

```
<div><textarea id="e1"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea id="e2"></textarea></div>
<div id="e3"/>

var dangerous = '<scri' + 'pt>alert("Danger!");</scri' + 'pt>';
document.getElementById('e1').value = dangerous;

document.getElementById('e2').innerHTML = dangerous;

dangerous = '</textarea>' + dangerous;
var content = '<textarea>' + dangerous + '</textarea>';
document.getElementById('e3').innerHTML = content;

console.log('Done.');
```

This creates two `textarea` elements with a script inside (save) and an empty one.

In the last test, I close the `textarea` in the input and then append the script.
Interestingly enough, setting `innerHTML` is safe to use in this case: [It doesn't execute scripts inserted in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml).

So as long as you do it in JavaScript, you're pretty safe. But usually, you render the DOM of the page on the server and then you must make sure you properly escape the content of the `textarea` because:

```
String unfilteredInput = "</textarea><script>alert(\"Danger!\");</script>";

out.write("<textarea>");
out.write(content);
out.write("</textarea>");
```

will execute the script.

Note: I also tried to demonstrate `document.write()` but that's not allowed in a JSFiddle. I'm pretty sure that `document.write()` is vulnerable to the same attack.

Comment: +1 Yes, it depends whether it is set server side or client side, although you're right in that `document.write()` is also vulnerable. A quick example of this here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1075151/dwrite.htm (works in Chrome).

Comment: Note that example "e3" is still vulnerable to XSS attacks! It doesn't work with `script` tags but for example with `style` tags, like this: `var dangerous = "<style onload='alert(\"Danger!\")'/>";`. See this modified JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uzLv6kj8/