# Use ajax to transport JavaScript data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
raise.js:

window.onload=init;
function init(){
    var submit=document.getElementById("submit");
    submit.onclick=sub;
}

function sub(){
    var url="raise.php";
    var title=document.getElementById("title");//title of a question
    var content=document.getElementById("inputContent");//content of a question

    var checktype=document.getElementsByName("type");
    var type;//type of a question
    if(checktype[0].checked){
        type="java";
    }
    else if(checktype[1].checked){
        type="c++";
    }
    else{
        type="html";
    }

    var point=document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var reward=point[0].value;//reward point

    url=url+"?title="+title.value;
    url=url+"?content="+content.value;
    url=url+"?type="+type;
    url=url+"?reward="+reward;

    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){
        alert("asde");
    }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","utf-8");
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

raise.php:

```
<?php
  echo "<script>alert('123')</script>";
 $title=$_GET['title'];
 $content=$_GET['content'];
 $reward=$_GET['reward'];
 $type=$_GET['type'];
?>
```

that confuses me alert('123') is not executed but alert("asde") is ,I want to know why..and am I right while trying to retrieve these data with php...I'm not very familiar with ajax...please show me some codes based on my data..thank you very much..

Comment: The alert is activated out of your context so you don't see it.
You will probably be able to see the file output in using _inspect element_

Comment: There are literally billions of records about such topic, you can read them [even synchronously].

Comment: does it mean I can retrieve data like this $title=$_GET['title']? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script element won't do anything unless it is part of a rendered HTML document.

The server returns it to the browser, then it sits in `xmlhttp.responseText` where you are ignoring it.

(That said, even if you didn't ignore it, you [might still have problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)).

Answer (score 0):

You simply not attaching the response body (the JavaScript) to your DOM, try:

```
// ...
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){
        alert("asde");
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        // here you have to attach xmlHttp.responseText to your DOM
    }
}
// ...
```

This should alert you "asde" and after that "script>alert('123')/script>"

Answer (score 0):

You better use Jquery with Ajax to POST or GET data instead of only Ajax. You can have a look here [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Here you will find out where alert should be used.