# can Javascript be called from inside innerHtml code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web site which inserts content via javascript's innerhtml function when a link is clicked (click it again and poof, the inserted data goes away).  This works great.  When I want to do now is add a flot plot to that injected code.  The flot plot needs the javascript to run after it is inserted.  Is this possible?  The alternate would be a button in the inserted code to then run the JS... but that's not ideal.  Thoughts? --Thanks!

Okay.. so here is some code:    This first bit is the link that you click:

```
<a name = "<?php echo $tag_no ?>" class="none" href="#<?php echo $tag_no ?>" title = "<?php echo $tooltip ?>" onClick="sendRequest('GET','/2.0/details.php3?event_no=<?php echo $tag_no ?>&amp;details=0&amp;PHPSESSID=<?php echo session_id() ?>')"><?php echo $concert_date_formatted ?> </a></td>
```

It calls the javascript functions here:

```
function sendRequest(method, url){
    //alert(method);
    if(method == 'get' || method == 'GET'){
        http.open(method,url,true);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            handleResponse(url,method);
        }
        http.send(null);
    } else if (method == "got" || method == "GOT"){
        handleResponse(url,method);
    }
}

function handleResponse(url,method){
    //alert("Junebug!");
    if(method == "GOT" || method == "got"){
        //document.getElementById(event_no).innerHTML = null;
        //alert("got");
        BetterInnerHTML(event_no,null);
    } else if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        var response = http.responseText;
        var equals = url.indexOf('=');
        var andsign = url.indexOf('&');
        var event_no = url.substring(equals + 1, andsign);
        if(response){
            //alert(response);
            document.getElementById(event_no).innerHTML = response;
            //BetterInnerHTML(event_no,response);
        }
    } 

}
```

Which in turn insert the code.

Comment: Post some code is a good start if you want help

Comment: AFAIK this won't work. Appending entire `<script>`-tags to the document using DOM manipulation functions `document.createElement`, `someELement.appendChild`, ...) however works.

Comment: See [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml) (basically, no: script elements inserted via innerHTML are *not* evaluated, which I can imagine has roots in early AJAX usage and security implications, but "work-abouts" exist)

Comment: if you want help, help us and put your code.

Comment: Laaposto, Rodrigo, code is included above, thank you for reminding me that like myself you cannot read minds!  Johannes can you elaborate on the method you suggest works?   user2864740  I agree it may be a security hole that was plugged.  Is that a particularly useful work around?

Comment: Johannes H.  do you have an example that uses the method you noted as working?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an IFRAME inside that DIV and use `document.write` into that IFRAME:

```
document.getElementById(event_no).innerHTML = "<iframe></iframe>";
document.getElementById(event_no).firstChild.contentWindow.document.write(response);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5B3Qs/

Comment: Yuriy... this seems to work... I am not familiar with iframes much... and the iframe appears small.. it should match the container width and length is defined by the length of the contents... can I make it do that?

Comment: You can manipulate IFRAME's size via width/height attributes. E.g. to make it fit the parent DIV try setting them to 100%: `"<iframe width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>"` See more IFRAME attributes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: ah cool, I should have checked before asking.. it can be modified in the same way as other html elements.  I'll see what happens!

Comment: The iframe is cool and everything but it seems unable to get the height set to the contents.  I have tried a variety of methods.  Do you know of a way to set the height based on the incoming contents?

Comment: Do you really want iframe to auto-resize? Was this what the original DIV did?

Comment: The original innerhtml added the contents to the page without scroll bars, just extended the page by the half to three quarters of a page that the details it inserted were worth.  The page was still flat in essence.

Comment: It may be getting overly complicated, you may want to rethink the design. Meanwhile take a look at this: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/09/30/resize-iframe-after-content-has-been-resized/ (it uses MS library, but doing the same in jQuery should be trivial)