# How to execute a javascript function that is in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

There should be a simple solution this this issue but I am not being able to figure it out!!
So I am getting data/templates via ajax. And there are some function in the ajax data. When I try to call the function it throws and error. Example in jsfiddle with regular vs ajax function calls. http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/b05uxko6/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="regularData">
  <h2>Regular Data</h2>
  <p onclick="mouseEvent()">Click Me</p>
   <script>
        function mouseEvent(){
            alert('Yep clicked');
        }
   </script>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="ajaxData"></div>



<!-- Javascript -->
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // do we need this?
        request.open("POST", "https://kvdevl06.sohalo.com/apps/kobie/php/widget/dispatcher_tpl.php");
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(request.readyState === 4){
                alert('Ajax data is: ' + request.response);
                document.getElementById("ajaxData").innerHTML = request.response;
            }
        }
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send("action=getTest&partner_user_id=1&template_id:test");
```

Comment: So, what is the error and what line of code does it occur on?  This is basic information that should be included with your question.

Comment: why dont you use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You may check the following question:
[Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)

In short, you may iterate the script tags and `eval` them.