# insert script tags into html element using innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, tags, innerhtml

I'm having trouble inserting this code into my HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var1 = "1";
var2 = "2";
var3 = "3";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.someadress.com/sss.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://someadress" target="_blank"><img src="someimg" width="468"
height="60"></a></noscript>';
```

I've tried using `innerhtml`, but it just doesn't seem to work. Here is an example of what i have tried; I'm trying to add the script inside the element with ID `allImages`:

```
    var imagesHTML = document.getElementById("allImages").innerHTML;
    imagesHTML = '<script type="text/javascript">
    var1 = "1";
    var2 = "2";
    var3 = "3";
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.someadress.com/sss.js"></script>
    <noscript><a href="http://someadress" target="_blank"><img src="someimg" width="468"
    height="60"></a></noscript>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load `<script>` tags by injecting HTML. Instead, you need to use `eval()` functions! There are other ways of creating DOM Objects and invoking scripts. Please check out these:

- [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml).
- [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

**Note:** You should **never** use `eval()`, unless you know the environment and is absolutely necessary.

If you don't need the hassle of these things, you can always use libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [MooTools](http://mootools.com/) to insert HTML using `.html()` function.

Comment: *"Instead, you need to use `eval()` functions!"* No, you don't. And arguably *really shouldn't*.

Comment: Separately: Since you know this is a duplicate of a previous question, even going to the trouble to link to it, why not close the question as a duplicate?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Updated the answer. Please do check it out.

Comment: *"Instead, you need to use `eval()` functions!"* is still there, and still incorrect.

Comment: the duplicated answer dosent seem to aim to 1 good solution+ i'm having trouble understanding the code,i use the script for the whole html or each time for diffrent tags?