# script inserted with innerHTML not executing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to ad a script and execute it on a certain place of the page but although the code displays on the page when I inspect the dom, it doesn't get executed.

I'm calling this from the head:

```
function include (selector) {

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        var selection = document.querySelector(selector);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var text = "<script src='myscript.js'></scr"+"ipt>"+
            "<script>"+
                "(function(){"+
                    "console.log('oh yes');"+
                    "myscript()"+
                "})();"+
            "</scr"+"ipt>";
            div.innerHTML = text;
        if (selection.nextSibling) {
            selection.parentNode.insertBefore(div, selection.nextSibling);
        }
        else {
            selection.parentNode.appendChild(div);
        }
    });
}
```

I never get "oh yes" in my console. Does anyone know why this happens?

I've checked this 2 answers:
[Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)
and
[Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)
The first one doesn't work for strings containing  tags, and the second one just offers a script and no explanation. I'd like to understand if it is possible in this case, and how to make it work, or where to put that function.