# Append <script> into <div> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a `<script>` tag into my `<div>`. Whenever I try to do this, the script just doesn't loads. But it works if I hard coded it under the  tag.

But if I try to append an `<img>` tag, it works!

Here's a partial code to give you some ideas.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tag = '<script src="xxx.js"></script>'; // file to grab images
    var tag2 = '<img src="some image link"></img>';
    $('#test').append(tag); //testing
    $('#test2').append(tag2); //testing
});
```

On HTML

```
<div id="test"></div> <!-- Not Working! -->
<div id="test2"></div> <!-- This Works! -->

<div id="test"><script src="xxx.js file to grab images"></script></div> <!-- This Works too! -->
```

Edit with more info below:

I've actually looked for solutions over the net and most of the answer are almost the same as the ones given here. In my case, it is slightly different from the others. That's because the tag variable is actually a must from database.

```
<?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM users_loc WHERE method='script'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

and on javascript side:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tag = <? echo $row['code'] ?>;
        var tag2 = <? echo $row2['code'] ?>;
        $('#test').append(tag); //testing
        $('#test2').append(tag2); //testing
    });
```

On my site, users will input their external image source into my database, and I will grab the source and display it on my site. But the problem arise when a user put in a `<script>` tag which works if it were hard coded into the `<div>`

I kept having this error message on my console "A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored."

I hope this answers the confusions. Thanks.

Edit: I think this is the problem with append: [Does Jquery append() behave asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085228/does-jquery-append-behave-asynchronously)

Comment: What is `file to grab images` in `src`?

Comment: the xxx.js file is able to grab images from the server and return it.

Comment: you need to check your xxx.js file and see wether it returns images correctly. Also note that images may be returned as bitstream, so you may need to decode that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [script inserted with innerHTML not executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287119/script-inserted-with-innerhtml-not-executing)

Comment: This really, really, sounds like a XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Why would you want to add a script nested in specific element? Instead ask question regarding your issue, not regarding workaround you think would fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all because about the parsing problem. The problem showing up after found `</script>` this code. It's assume we want to close the script tag but we won't. In order to avoid that, put `\` before `/` like so to escape special character :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tag = '<script src="xxx.js"><\/script>'; // file to grab images
  var tag2 = '<img src="some image link"></img>';
  $('#test').append(tag); //testing
  $('#test2').append(tag2); //testing
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/b1d44yxs/1/)**

Try inspect the element in chrome to see the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'xxx.js';

$('#test').append(script);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message on my console also : "A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored."

Answer (score 0):

If it matters where in the source order the script tag is injected, Mario Araque's solution is for you. If it does not matter, R3tep's solution does the job nicely.