# Execute javascript that is loaded from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create/change a javascript array based on what is return from an ajax call. This is what I am working with so far:

```
function ajaxCall(code) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","ShowBusiness",false);
    xmlhttp.send(code);
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

and then within that response HTML I have (among other elements)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    images = [1, 2, 3];
</script>
```

However, when I then try to use `console.log(images);` within a function that was in the original page, it tells me that "images is not defined". I then tried to go back and insert a `var images = [];` into the head of the original page, but then the console log returns [], not what I hope to change as a result of the ajax call.

Any ideas how I can get around this? I assume that the page is not recognizing the javascript that I am inserting into the page with ajax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Use json to handle values sent via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendChild()` instead :

```
function ajaxCall(code) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","ShowBusiness",false);
    xmlhttp.send(code);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think script tags get executed on insertion. Check the answers in this question (or the **edit** of the original question) for a couple of solutions:

[Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)