# JS loading external HTML that should load the HTML's assets (CSS and JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I've written the snippet below to send  an HTTP request to get an HTML file.  The HTML file has CSS and JS included (link and script tags):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'form.html', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    var resp = request.responseText;

    this.innerHTML = resp;
  } else {

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {

};

request.send();
```

The above snippet sends a request and gets the HTML.  However, it's having problems putting the HTML into the DOM and it's not sending requests to fetch the styles and javascript.  How can I do the above and take the response HTML, put it into the page, and have it send the requests to get the various assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onload` handler, `this` refers to the `request` object, not the document, so setting the `innerHTML` property won't do anything useful. You need to tell it where to put the new HTML, e.g.

```
request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    var resp = request.responseText;

    document.documentElement.innerHTML=resp;
  } else {

  }
}
```

(Note this won't work in early IE versions)

Comment: That's working now, but the JS still isn't coming in.

Comment: The JS inside of `form.html` isn't being loaded.

Comment: You mean inline script is not being executed? Yeah, that won't work - perhaps one of the answers to this question would work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: Yeah `form.html` has a bunch of `<script src="file.js"></script>` in it.

Comment: Not inline.  I used the snippet from that answer, and it's running the inline now.  But I ALSO need to make sure it sends the request to get the JS from the `<script>` tags

Comment: sorry, on a train with dreadful network coverage at the moment so can't help much - should be possible to find and re-inject the script `src="..."` elements via DOM manipulation to have them load

Comment: Can you add an example to your answer?

Comment: Any idea why the code from that answer is working for inline script tags, but not ones with an `src` attribute?

Comment: Apologies, just back to netland now. I presume you used the accepted answer? There's one further down that deals with `src` attributes - here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26716182/1469259 - let me know if that works, and if so I'll edit it into the answer.

Comment: (and the reason is that the accepted answer doesn't copy the `src` attribute to the newly-created `script` element, so if you prefer to stick with the more elaborate script you should be able to just add `script.src = elem.src` after `script` is created to get it to work)