# Running Javascript in new window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running this function to open a new window.

```
function htmlNewWindow(id) {
    var html = $(id).html();
    var newWindow = window.open('');
    newWindow.document.body.innerHTML =  '<html><head><title>Hi</title>  <script src="js/myScript.js"></script> </head>' + html;    
}
```

This successfully creates a new window with the HTML in it. I have a bunch of HTML tags which when clicked run a function called Foo1. I've tried printing the entire function of Foo1 to the new HTML document, and tried putting Foo1 inside myScript.js. I see both Foo1 inside a script tag in the new window, and  but neither are loaded since they are just written to the new page as HTML.

Comment: Scripts don't run when you assign them to `.innerHTML`. You need to call `createElement('script')` and add it to the window's DOM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: `...body.innerHTML = '<html><head>...` - doesn't this look a little... odd?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: You are putting a complete HTML document inside the body of another HTML document.  What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Scripts added with `.innerHTML` aren't executed. You need to create a `script` node and append it to the window's DOM.

```js
$("#button").click(newWindow);

function newWindow(id) {
  var html = $(id).html();
  var win = window.open('');
  win.document.head.innerHTML = '<title>Hi</title></head>';
  win.document.body.innerHTML = '<body>' + html + '</body>';
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'js/myScript.js';
  win.document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```

This doesn't run in Stack Snippet's sandbox, here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/deohu685/1/).

Comment: Thanks this worked, I was looking the the wrong places for the solution. I wasn't aware I could append new node types to a new window in this manner. Thanks again!

Comment: I want to know pure JS alternative to this.

Comment: @Y.Yoshii Change `$(id).html()` to `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var newWindow = window.open('');
newWindow.document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'js/myScript.js';
newWindow.document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone has this to be done in a link. Do the following:

```
<a href="javascript: var n= window.open('/url/to/page/in/SAMEDOMAIN'); n.focus(); n.addEventListener('load', n.alert('replace this with a good thing'), true);">Link</a>
```

This opens a new window with that URL, it set the focus to that windows, and as soon as the 'load' event is triggered, it executes the code in the function. It only works with a page in the same domain.

Hope this helps ⬆✌.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you create, and then append a script file within a new window:

```
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
//creates script in current document
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
//set it to JS by "type"
fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
//set your "src=yourFile_href_Here.js" 


//Then create your newWindow as you did above, but slightly updated
//Create your function which will consume the "fileref" argument
function htmlNewWindow(fileref) {
    var newWindow = window.open('');
    newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}; //right now the function is made but you still have to execute it

//Execute your function, and pass it the variable "fileref" that you set above.    

htmlNewWindow(fileref);
//Within this edit you will append the head element
//with your newly created script(or any other parameterized argument)

/* Replace your filename to pass any other script */
```

NOTE - Opening a page residing on a different domain, if not specifically allowed, will reject instances of this due to CORS(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

It's not a safe practice to be sending your scripts into other people's pages or allowing them in your own if your domain hasn't sent them.  Also, depending on your server/technology stack you may need to configure your *-origin settings within your backend stack.  See here: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)