# Send data over to another html file

Tags: javascript, html, database, frontend

I am trying to get certain data from my database on my (1) HTML page and display it on the (2) HTML page.

My codes for (1) html file:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    .
    .
    .
    <button item="' + count + '" onclick="getData(this)">Example</button>
    .
    .
    .
</body>

</html>
```

And the JS for it:

```
        .
        .
        .
        var currentIndex = 0;

        //This function is to display the details of an individual item
        function getData(element) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open("GET", "/theroute", true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.onload = function () {
                var example = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                var item = element.getAttribute("item");
                currentIndex = item;

                document.getElementById("data1").textContent = example[item].name;
                document.getElementById("data2").src = example[item].age;
            }
            request.send();
        }
        .
        .
        .
```

I want to get these data in my (2) HTML page (for example):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h4 id="data1"></h4>
    <h4 id="data2"></h4>
</body>

</html>
```

I saw this [Get data from one html file and display it using another html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774775/get-data-from-one-html-file-and-display-it-using-another-html-file), but I'm not sure how to use this for my case here.

Sorry, I am new to this, so giving a detailed explanation for your solution would be very helpful. I am using vanilla JS only so please no jQuery. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The above snippets are a little unclear. Are you generating the initial HTML with a serverside language and database? ( php & mysql perhaps ) You cannot have two elements with the same ID ( `<h4 id='data1'></h4>` ) and you cannot send the response of an ajax call to another HTML page and hope that it will be there  next time you look...

Comment: sorry, for the ID part it was a typo. And yes, I am trying to get data from mysql database.

Comment: fetching data from the db to display on the same page? That is easy. Fetching data to display on another page ( different from the page making the request ) is an entirely different problem and will not be done like this. Please clarify which

Comment: I am fetching the data to display on another page.

Comment: who will see the data on the other page? Will that person be on both pages simultaneously?

Comment: No. Picture it like a search list, where i click on one of the items, it brings me to the item's page. But I want to get the item data / id and send it over to the 2nd page.

Comment: OK - that is an important distinction to make.

Comment: sorry about the incovenience

Comment: ok, can you show the response data or the JSON data?

Comment: Also - the `dataset` attribute might be of interest. They allow you to legitimately assign custom `data-PARAM=VALUE` type attributes to HTML elements. By convention you should not add your own attributes to html elements for the markup to remain valid.

Comment: The output of `console.log(request.responseText)` is `[{"_id":1, "name":"test","age":10}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206578/discussion-between-ramraider-and-cbch).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might prove of use to you. The button(s) have had the custom `item` attribute replaced with the `dataset` equivalent to ensure the html is valid. Normally I'd suggest also using external event handlers rather than adding `onclick=getdata()` to the elements inline but for brevity here they remain.The function, when invoked by clicking a button, will construct the relevant querystring to send to the endpoint ( for you it would be `/theroute?id=X&name=Y&age=Z` etc ) which queries the database and sends the response back. The response is used to generate the menu of hyperlinks which take the user to page 2 when clicked. I think this is what you were trying to explain. You could copy the entire code and create a new page to see in action.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && !empty( $_GET['item'] ) ){
        ob_clean();

        /* 
            emulate "/theroute" and send some data back to the ajax callback.

            This data would really be fetched from the database but below is
            simply randomly generated data for display/test purposes.
        */


        $payload=[];
        $item=$_GET['item'];
        for( $i=0; $i < 10; $i++ ){
            $payload[]=[
                'id'    =>  $i,
                'name'  =>  'Geronimo '.uniqid().' '.$item,
                'age'   =>  mt_rand(16,80)
            ];
        }
        exit( json_encode( $payload ) );
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function getData( e ) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var ul=document.getElementById('menu');
                /* The above PHP code is to emulate the real endpoint /theroute */

                xhr.open( "GET", location.href +'?task=fetch&item='+e.target.dataset.item, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    var json = JSON.parse( xhr.response );
                    json.forEach(obj=>{

                        var id=obj.id;
                        var name=obj.name;
                        var age=obj.age;

                        var li=document.createElement('li');
                            li.appendChild( createhyperlink(id,name,age) );                     
                        ul.appendChild( li );
                    });
                }
                xhr.send();
            }

            function createhyperlink(id,name,age){
                var a=document.createElement('a');
                    a.href='page2.html?id='+id+'&name='+name+'&age='+age;
                    a.innerHTML='View '+name;
                return a;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='menu'></ul>
        <?php
            for( $i=1; $i <=10; $i++ ){
                echo "<button data-item='{$i}' onclick='getData(event)'>Example #{$i}</button>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So sorry about this but im only using vanilla JS.

Comment: the above is vanilla javascript

Comment: i don't have php available for my case

Comment: Ok - the PHP is not important. I used PHP here simply to create the initial HTML (buttons) and to process the ajax request ( which would be some other server side language unknown to me and undisclosed in question )... the important bit is processing the ajax response and creating suitable `links` to take the user to page 2

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, let's discuss at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206578/discussion-between-ramraider-and-cbch