# How can I get my button when clicked in an window open on an image to work it is not calling the function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that gets an image along with it's height and width. I open the image in a new window using window.open I defined an `onclick` so that if anyplace on the image is clicked the window closes, this works fine. I have defined a button and located it outside the image in the new window. When that button is clicked it calls another function, this does not work. Is there away to make this work?

I have tried several different ways of making this work. I have tried removing the close when clicking on the image and that did not work. I have tried putting the button on the image and that did not work.

```
function showImg(imgSrc, H, W) { 
    newImg = window.open("", "", config = "height=" + H + ",width=" + W + "");
    newImg.document.write("<img src='" + imgSrc + "' height='" + H + "' width='" + W + "'class=photoPreview onclick='window.close()' style='position:absolute;left:0;top:0'>");
    newImg.document.write('<input type="button" id="btn_makedefault" onclick=saveMe(); style="color: black; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0";title="Save Image"; value="Save"></button>');
    newImg.document.close();
    newImg.focus();
}
```

I want the Save button to remain at the bottom of the window and when clicked to call the other function saveMe().

Comment: The code you've posted will not do what you describe, and there is no save button or associated function.  Please post all the relevant code, preferably in working snippet (use the `<>` button in the editor)

Comment: How are you passing your function to the new window? As Archer said you need to show your code. Also see here for similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357312/running-javascript-in-new-window-open

Comment: `onclick="saveMe();"`

Comment: Where is the `saveMe()` function?

Comment: Also you have `<input></button>` change input to button.

Comment: When I change the onclick=saveMe() to onclick="saveMe();" did not make a difference.

Comment: The saveMe() function is function saveMe(){ alert("Save Me"); }

Comment: Changed the <input> to <button> and that still has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the onclick=saveMe(); to onclick="opener.saveMe()"; and that appears to work just the way I need it to work. Thanks for all the help.

'''
function showImg(imgSrc, H, W) { 
    newImg = window.open("", "", config = "height=" + H + ",width=" + W + "");
    newImg.document.write("");
    newImg.document.write('');
    newImg.document.close();
    newImg.focus();
}
'''