# Button click and 2 webpages

Tags: javascript, html

Problem Statement: A User clicks on a button. It opens a new webpage in a new window. We check if the user has spent 5 seconds on this newly opened page. If yes, then page provides a link to another webpage. At last, the new webpage appears when the user clicks on the button. is it possible to do this in Javascript?

Things I know:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="timerPage()">Click me </button>
```

Javascript (in the head of the website)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function timerpage()
{
window.open("timerPageUrl");
/* I believe after this point we don't have any control on this window.
Please correct me if I am wrong.
*/
}
</script>
```

I am able to create a "timer page with a click" separately but merging these two into one seems near to impossible to me. Well, I need some help.

Comment: So there will be a total of 3 pages? On each page, create a JS separately

Comment: Thanks for replying. Well, I only have a Url for the new page. Nothing else.I am not allowed to use Iframe too.

Comment: So you don't have access or modify the source code of the new window? Are they even on the same domain?

Comment: no, they are not on the same domain. But is it possible to control the new window created from the button click?

Comment: Then you can't apply JS on another webpage, especially what you don't own. The JS must be inside the other webpage. Thread closes :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

window.open returns a WindowProxy object which represents the newly created window.

In combination with [settimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) you might be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying, so basically you are saying. On the button click. I open a new webpage and redirect that webpage to another page after say 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a script to append the new content to the page after certain time - 5 secs in your example - the steps depends on where you want to open the new window

- **newly created window:**  check this thread [Running Javascript in new window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357312/running-javascript-in-new-window-open)
- **iFrame** check this thread [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

the code needed to run in the new window is something like

```js
window.setTimeout(function(){
 document.body.innerHTML = "<h1> this works after 5 secs! </h1>"
}, 500)
```