# How do I open a new blank window and make the new blank window show an alert in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have tried
`open(alert("Hi!")`

I was also wondering how you would put a prompt response from someone into the alert on the new blank window as well.
I tried

```
let answer = prompt("What is your fave drink?")
if (answer ==null){
window.alert(answer)
else{
window.open()
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357312/running-javascript-in-new-window-open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Javascript in new window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357312/running-javascript-in-new-window-open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.open()` [accepts a URL as an argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
You would need another page to open the alert, and pass the URL of that page, for example: `window.open("https://mypage.com/alert")`

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question.