# Jquery datepicker does not work on a newly opened blank window

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I tried apply jquery datepicker on a newly opened blank window (opened with window.open).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 
 
</body>
</html>

  <script>
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.id = 'button';
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  
  $('#button').on('click', function() {

      newWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=700, height=1000');
      var div = newWindow.document.createElement('div');
      div.style.textAlign = "center";
      div.id = "div_riaszt_kuldes"; 
      newWindow.document.body.appendChild(div);
      input2 = $('<input id="datepicker" type="text">', [,newWindow.document.body]);
      $(input2).appendTo(newWindow.document.body);
      $(input2).datepicker();
  }); 
  
  
  </script>
```

When I call datepicker, the following error occurs:

*jquery-3.6.0.js:6401 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'defaultView')
at getStyles (jquery-3.6.0.js:6401:33)
at curCSS (jquery-3.6.0.js:6585:25)
at Function.css (jquery-3.6.0.js:6996:10)
at jquery-3.6.0.js:7145:12
at access (jquery-3.6.0.js:4203:15)
at jQuery.fn.init.css (jquery-3.6.0.js:7127:10)
at datepicker_getZindex (jquery-ui.js:7333:19)
at HTMLInputElement._showDatepicker (jquery-ui.js:8130:31)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.js:5430:27)
at elemData.handle (jquery-3.6.0.js:5234:28)*

The elem.ownerDocument is a null object specifically.

However, when I opened the new window as _parent, everything works like a charm.

Comment: Not sure if it actually set up to correctly handle things when used like this, across "document boundaries." You might have to inject jquery & jqueryUI into the popup first, and then initialize the datepicker "in" there, the normal way.

Comment: could you please provide stackblitz.

Comment: you mean what output generated running this code on stackblitz?
there was no error but nothing happened clicking on the input object

Comment: URL of the project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-hn9iop?file=index.js

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357610/6133426) help?

Comment: Yes! It helped! I had to add the jquery libraries to the new window and my own js script which calls datepicker. Thanks for the hint!