# Dynamically Adding JavaScript Code To Page

Tags: javascript

This question is linked with [Frustrating innerHTML Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516075/frustrating-innerhtml-issue).

Since this question was a duplicate of another question, so I referred to that question for a solution. I adopted the 2nd answer in the list (with 37 votes). So that I used this coding for dynamically adding javascript to my page.

```
<html>
<head><title>Javascript Using innerHTML</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setcode(code)  {
    document.write("<img src='empty.gif' onload='function msgbox(msg){alert(msg);};' />");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="">
<div id="hello">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<button onclick='setcode(document.getElementById("hello"))'>SET</button>
<button onclick='msgbox("what up man?!");'>CHECK</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the issue is that when I press the SET button, all my current page is removed out of existence and only the code within document.write() remains. Am I doing something wrong or what? Note that I want to add javascript coding to my page **without** removing the current visual objects :S

Comment: When you do document.write, you assign it a value, so previous value is erased. You will have to append value to a container. You can use this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650776/add-remove-html-inside-div-using-javascript) as reference

Answer (score 1):

> the issue is that when I press the SET button, all my current page is removed out of existence and only the code within document.write() remains

That's the expected behaviour for the `document.write` function.  It will overwrite all the content on the page.

You need to instead append content to the page you can use the following: `document.body.innerHTML += "<img src..">`

Your example would look as follows:

```
function setcode(code)  {
   document.body.innerHTML += "<img src='empty.gif' onload='function msgbox(msg){alert(msg);};' />";
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I should try this and see if it works.

Comment: OK It's not working. The code **is** being appended to the document body, but for reasons lame and unknown, the javascript part of it is not being _executed_. So that when I press the CHECK button, not message box appears as it should. However, when I edit the CHECK button coding to alert(document.body.innerHTML), it shows that the line was successfully appended by the SET button code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn;t the function msgbox be defined above the setcode function and not inside the onload attribute of an image?

Comment: As the title implies, the aim of the coding is to **dynamically** add javascript code to the page. If I had any hard-defined code at the start of the page, I would simply have added it in the head section and done with it. Also, check out the question linked at the top. I think the whole innerHTML approach for this purpose is incorrect. As I was being able to successfully add the code in a DIV's innerHTML in the previous question and that was also not being _executed_

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a brilliant working solution for my problem. It is the second answer posted at [Can I add javascript dynamically to an existing script element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619484/can-i-add-javascript-dynamically-to-an-existing-script-element)

```
<html>
<head><title>Javascript Using innerHTML</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setcode(code)  {
    var JS=document.createElement("script");
    JS.text="function msgbox(msg){alert(msg);}";
    document.body.appendChild(JS);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="">
<div id="hello">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<button onclick='setcode(document.getElementById("hello"))'>SET</button>
<button onclick='msgbox("hello");'>CHECK</button>
</body>
</html>
```

works flawlessly without any glitch or issue. Thanks to kennebec for the answer.