# javascript code in XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, xslt

I'm using XSLT to transform an XML into HTML on the client side (Chrome browser).

I'm trying to add `<script>` HTML tag to the XSLT but it seems that the code in it is never evaluated on the generated HTML, although I've specified `defer`.
On the other hand, `onclick` event itself runs OK.

Here is an example of the XSLT which demonstrates the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
<xsl:text>
<![CDATA[
function test(){
  window.alert('Test');
}
 ]]>
 </xsl:text>
</script>


</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="window.alert('Test')">This works</button>      
  <br/>
  <button onclick="test()">This does not work</button>      
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML file does not matter is this example. You can try the above example on [W3Schools online XSLT transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog)

In this example, clicking on `This does not work` yields an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

### Update

The problem only happens when I'm performing the XSLT transformation itself in javascript. Here is the piece of code that is doing that in my case:

```js
var processor = new XSLTProcessor(),
  htmlResult;

processor.importStylesheet(xsl);
htmlResult = processor.transformToFragment(xhr.responseXML, document);
document.getElementById("result").appendChild(htmlResult);
```

### Update

I also need the following to work correctly when they appear in the XSLT file:

- Loading external javascript files using `script` element:
  `<script type="text/javascript" src="/somelibrary.js" />`
- Bare `<script>` elements with javascript code in them, that call functions which are declared in an external javascript file, loaded by an earlier `script` element.

Comment: not sure - works in firefox, not in edge or chrome

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the problem, the XML document is http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015111601.xml, your XSLT is http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015111601.xsl, Chrome 46 on Windows 10 shows an alert box for both buttons, no script error is shown in the console. Don't use the w3schools test bed to run XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen It is reproduced on my local sever. W3Schools was only given as an example. I will try to give another example, with some other online tool other than W3Schools.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015111601.xml? Which version of Chrome on which platform is that?

Comment: @MartinHonnen no, as you said, in [your test](http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015111601.xml) the problem is not reproduced. I suspect it may be related to the fact that the XML is transformed **in javascript** (both on W3Schools and maybe also in my local reproducible case). I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: It seems to be a known problem with Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=266305, they don't seem to make any effort to fix it. The bug reporter says that doing `document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.importNode(htmlResult, true))` instead of the direct `appendChild` fixes the problem with Chrome, I have not tested that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have researched, this is a known bug in Chrome reported in 2013 in https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=266305. It does not look as any effort has been taken to fix it. However, the bug reporter also found a workaround, instead of using `appendChild` or `insertBefore` or similar to insert the fragment returned by `transformToFragment` directly into the document, if you call `importNode` first on the fragment, the `script` elements are then executed when you insert the imported fragment into the document.

I have written a test case http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015111606.html which works fine for me a current version of Chrome on Windows, it uses

```
  var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
  proc.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
  targetElement.appendChild(targetElement.ownerDocument.importNode(proc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, targetElement.ownerDocument), true));
```

However, do note that Microsoft Edge neither with the normal approach of calling `appendChild` on the fragment nor with the above Chrome workaround executes the script element's code.

Comment: `importNode` approach didn't work for me when the XSLT contained references to external javascript resources: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/library.js" defer="defer"></script>`. The embedded javascript code could not use `library.js`.

Comment: In http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015111701.html the script loads and transforms an XSLT stylesheet creating an HTML `script` with an external source file and that is loaded and executed fine by Chrome.

Comment: And in http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015111702.html Chrome runs the external script where one function `foo` is declared and one function call is done, and the `input` button created also is able to call the button `foo` successfully. I have not tried to use `defer`, as I am not sure why that would be needed.

Comment: Your example include `script` element and an `input` element that uses that external script in its `onclick` action. However, In my case, I have a **bare `script` element in the XSL file that explicitly calls a function which is declared in an external .js file** (Indeed this part does not appear on my original question, I will revise it). This part is missing from your example and this is what's not working well with `importNode`. (while having the same function call on an action attribute such as `onclick` works well)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: (inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716182/619493))

```js
                function insertAndExecute(id, htmlResult) {                
                    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(htmlResult);
                    var scripts = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("script");
                    var deferreds = [];

                    // First load all external scripts
                    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {                  
                        if (scripts[i].src != "") {
                            deferreds.push($.getScript(scripts[i].src));
                        }
                    }

                    // Execute other (inline) scripts after all external scripts are loaded                 
                    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
                        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {                  
                            if (!scripts[i].src) {
                                $.globalEval(scripts[i].innerText || scripts[i].textContent);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }


var processor = new XSLTProcessor(),
                            htmlResult;

processor.importStylesheet(xsl);
htmlResult = processor.transformToFragment(xhr.responseXML, document);                      

// The htmlResult may contain javascript code. Scan and run it
insertAndExecute("result", htmlResult);
```