# How to process javascript from XMLHttpRequest donwnloaded file?

Tags: javascript

I want to execute javascript from downloaded `html` file. I use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the html response.

```
function load2element() {

    localStorage.setItem("geadele", "cool variable is passed");

    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', '/geadele/geadele/gesurvey.html');
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
        el.innerHTML = client.responseText; // << file with javascript 
    }

    client.send();
}
```

imported `gesurvey.html` contains javascript codes for execution:

```
<script>
    console.log("From gesurvey.html");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("geadele")); // should "cool variable is passed"
</script>

<div>I am survey</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: Your usage of XMLHttpRequest#onreadystatechange is doomed to failure - you need to learn how to use XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

```
function load2element() {
  localStorage.setItem("geadele", "cool variable is passed");
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open('GET', '/geadele/geadele/gesurvey.html');
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var regex = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/g;
    var scriptContent = regex.exec(client.responseText);
    if (scriptContent.length) {
        var scriptTbExecuted = '"use strict"; ' + scriptContent[1];
        eval(scriptTbExecuted);
    }
  }
  client.send();
}
```

However, execution of eval is dangerous. strict mode eliminates some  harmful behaviours, but you need to read about eval in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) considering the what you want to and content of that script.

Comment: ahhh, good old regex on HTML - I hear [Tony's hooves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: you can do the above without resorting to eval, AND allow multiple script tags AND even allow script tags with src attribute AND without summoning ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ