# the <script> tag doesn't seem to work in bokeh Div

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, bokeh

I'm using bokeh to draw some interactive plots, and I also wanna add some html div as description for the plot. Part of my code:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div
div = Div(text="""<p>Title</p><script type="text/javascript">document.write("hi")</script>""")
show(widgetbox(div))
```

I excepted the output would be:

```
Title
hi
```

But I only got:

```
Title
```

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Bokeh `Div` objects only set `innerHTML` with the text given, as-is. In order to have a script execute, additional work must happen. See, for instance, the answers to [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml). Bokeh is extensible, so it is possible you could create a [Custom Extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) that does the required extra work to cause scripts to be evaluated.

Alternatively if you embed your Bokeh document in a custom template, you could put the script in template.

Comment: Thanks! Now I've tried templates for bokeh server, and the script in that works well!