# Calling a javascript function from an externally live loaded file on a div using vanilla javascript only

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a file (load.php) that is loaded on a "div" every second inside my home page (home.php). load.php has some JavaScript functions that get the values (cells[i].innerHTML) of a row, but the functions do not work when load.php is loaded on home.php, but works perfectly when load.php is loaded directly or included to home.php. both loading the page and calling the javascript function on load.php are the core functionality of this web app, please some assistance will be appreciated. below are the codes for both home.php and load.php

home.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="showReload"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function(){
            let showReload = document.getElementById('showReload');
            function reload(div, file){
                loadDiv(div, file);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    reload(div, file);
                }, 1000);

            }
            reload('showReload', 'load.php');
        }
            function loadDiv(div, files){
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else{
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open('GET',files,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

load.php

```
<?php  

echo date("Y/M/D,H:i:s");

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db_name = 'dataBaseName';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name) or die("Connect to database failed");

$fetch = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE status = 1");
if (!$fetch) {
    echo "Failed to fetch data from database";
    return false;
}
if ($fetch->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $fetch->fetch_assoc()) {
        $fname = $row['firstname'];
        $mname = $row['middlename'];
        $lname = $row['lastname'];
        $phone = $row['pnumber'];
        $id = $row['ID'];

        ?>
            <table id="table">
                <tr>
                    <td class="hide"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mname; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $phone; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php 
    }
}


?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    let table = document.getElementById('table'),
        rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
        cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        rows[i].onclick = function(){
            console.log(this.cells[3].innerHTML);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: Thanks but that's not what am looking for, am not looking a function that can pick the values of innerHTML, I already have that and it works perfectly, but the function does not work when the file (load.php) has been loaded to a div in home.php, I want to know how to make that function callable while load.php is being loaded unto the div