# Javascript loaded by an Ajax call doesn't execute?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

I´m trying to implement html code with Ajax-get into my temp-page.

This works as it should, only the javascript isn´t executed as I expected. If I load the code independently in the browser, then the javascript executes as expected. If it's implemented with Ajax in my temp-page it doesn´t. Why?

Here is the html and javascript code I'm loading:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/x/x/x/x/stylesheet.css">
<div id='content_Box'></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/x/x/x/x/javascript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And here is the ajax code which loads it:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    content_Box.innerHTML = "";

    content_Box.innerHTML = this.responseText;

    }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", Pfad, true);
    xhttp.send();
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: **content_Box** belongs to the external file. Hence, you cannot add to it before adding the external file to current document....

Comment: It´s added via var content_Box = document.getElementById("content_Box ");

Comment: How defined content_Box? What is response Ajax request?

Comment: Hi Evgeniy, what do you mean with defined and the response?

Comment: it´s defined in the index file and the response is what i get from the ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the ajax call.

The issue is that

```
content_Box.innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

doesn't cause any scripts to execute.

See [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml) for some code that looks at the text, finds the scripts, and executes them.

Comment: This sounds like the solution. Now I have to read about it first. But is this kind of implementation to load external pages via ajax and work with them not the way to go, if I have a navigation bar and want to switch between the pages?

Comment: Correct. The main JS frameworks – Angular, React, Vue, -- don't load javascript to execute it, they load html. You never need to *load* javascript – you can always just put it in the original page that does the loading.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what your js actually does.
Anyway you can call the functions once you have loaded the ajax response (in `xhttp.onreadystatechange`) to make sure to run them at least once also on the parts you got from the response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It loads some data from a database via ajax and creates div objects from that. My problem in understanding the whole thing is, after I included the code via html. How do I access the functions of my included file, which are in the javascript file and whicht is in the same folder as the included code. It sounds like I can just refer to them after the ajax call as you mentioned above, but this doesn´t do anything. I thought I just include the code and work with it, because I have already referred to the javascript file in the index of the include.

Comment: so you want to load more data from ajax after having received a first part, using the functions you wrote in the index.html file, right?

Comment: I want to load a external page into my main website via ajax and access the functions of that external page like I do when I open it in the browser. I thought this process would be the default way to do, if I´m using a template website with header and navigation, to switch between the katgeories.