# Is it a risk to pass html in an RESTful API response and inject directly into webpage?

Tags: reactjs, xss

I'm trying to understand if there is a chance for an [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) when our api endpoint returns a json response with a property returning html data:

e.g.

`https://www.link-to-my-website.com/api/v1/data`

Resp:

```
{
  footer: "<a href='https://www.link-to-my-website.com'>My Link</a>"
}
```

and then in React.js (or any js frontend) doing something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class MyFooterComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="footer" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.footer }} />
    );
  }
}
```

Am I putting my end users at risk? and should I sanitize or simply not pass data this way? Or am I too paranoid here?

Thank you!

Comment: is there user generated input?

Comment: no the footer html comes directly from a database that we manage input for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no user input, there is no XSS issue. From the owasp link:

> Flaws that allow these attacks to succeed are quite widespread and occur anywhere a web application uses input from a user within the output it generates without validating or encoding it.

If there was user input, then yes, you’d want to specifically sanitize that input before sending the response and injecting it into the html.

Comment: my understanding is that this is a flawed way of thinking about it. preventing attacks is a matter of weaving security into all of your code, and a level of distrust at app boundaries (e.g., the one between frontend and api) greatly aids in mitigating potential attacks. _if_ a hacker can compromise the API, now they can inject scripts into your frontend app. but if you simply don't return HTML from the API, and never use dangerouslySetInnerHTML in the frontend, there is a limit to how much damage a successful attack on the API can do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes such implementation is prone to script injection attacks. If u are maintaining the API it might not be that big of an issue but you should never do that with a third party API. But just to be safe dont go for that implementation. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml).