# Programmatically replacing `innerHTML` of whole document doesn't trigger loading JS?

Tags: javascript

I use JavaScript to programmatically replace my whole page on a button click:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    fetch("hqsc").then(r => {
        const txt = r.text();
        txt.then(t => {
            document.querySelector('html').innerHTML = t;
            console.log(t);
        });
    }).catch(console.log);
});
```

The page that is intended to be loaded is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }

        form#authenticate {
            width: 30vw;
            height: auto;
            margin: 20vh auto;
            border: 1px dashed black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: darkgray;
            padding: 15px 10px;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 120px 100px;
            grid-column-gap: 15px;
            grid-row-gap: 20px;
            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-row-start: 1;
        }
    </style>
    **<script type="module" src="/static/auth.js"></script>**

</head>

<body>
    <form id="authenticate">
        <label for="username">User</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" />

        <label for="password">Pass</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />

        <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

I noticed that the `/static/auth.js` javascript on the new page is completely ignored. Why is it ignored? How can I address this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it ignored?

For security reasons. See this comment from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations:

HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted with `innerHTML` [should not execute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0).

> How can I address this issue?

I would first and foremost recommend you address it by finding an alternative way to update your document. Resetting the entire HTML document as a result of a user action is likely going to cause many issues; I doubt this script issue will be the last unexpected side effect you find.

If you absolutely must use this method, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml) for some ideas for how to make it work.

Comment: I agree. You can store that _other HTML_ at a different address and programmatically  navigate there as in `window.location = "that-fancy-new-url";`