# Rails Running JS in Partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

When I render an html.erb partial the div shows up on the screen but the javascript is not firing, how can I get the javascript to run?

Controller render

```
render partial: 'success', status: 200
```

Partial _success.html.erb

```
<div class="js-hide notification is-primary mb-16">
  Success!
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  alert('this should run');
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(".js-hide").hide();
  }, 5000);
})
</script>
```

Stimulus Form Controller

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['input', 'status', 'form'];

  success(event) {
      const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail;
      this.statusTarget.innerHTML = xhr.response;
      this.inputTarget.value = '';
      this.formTarget.remove()
  }

  error(event) {
    const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail;
    this.statusTarget.innerHTML = xhr.response;
    this.inputTarget.value = '';
  }
}
```

Input form

```
<div class="mb-24" data-controller="form">
  <p data-target="form.status"></p>
  <%= form_with(model: email_follow, url: form_path(event),
                data: { action: 'ajax:success->form#success 
                          ajax:error->form#error', target: 'form.form' }
                ) do |form| %>
        
        <div class="field has-addons">
          <div class="control">
            <%= form.text_field :name, class: 'input', data: { target: 'form.input' } %>
          </div>
          <div class="control">
            <%= form.submit 'Submit', class: 'button is-info' %>
          </div>
        </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

RESULT:
Ended up adding the js code into my stimulus controller

Comment: Often, you'll see a [page change event](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events) handler. Have you looked into this?

Comment: @jvillian good thought, nothing is firing though, even the alert

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks? If so, you'll need to use the Turbolinks event handler.

Comment: @jvillian yes using turbolinks and stimulus to watch the form input, added the form into the question

Comment: @jvillian Not sure why that js doesn't run, I did find a solution, added the js into the stimulus controller that works just fine.. thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue as well, the problem is that content inserted with `innerHTML` will not execute any script tag within it. There are some more detailed discussions about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml).

Your option is either parsing the content and executing the scripts manually, or setting up other event listeners to catch that partial load.