# After dome-tree is loaded, you can load and execute more JavaScript files with a button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

If the browser has loaded the document and all external resources, you can load and fire via button/click based on *xmlhttprequest()* more JavaScript files and HTML documents with integrated JavaScript files?

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rq.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**rq.js**

```js
function put() {
  const xhrURL = 'load.php';
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', xhrURL, false);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function bar() {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
      document.head.innerHTML += xhr.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhr.send(null);
}

window.onload = function a() {
  // Button
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'click here';
  btn.value = 'click here';
  btn.type = 'button';
  btn.onclick = function p() {
    put();
  };

  document.body.appendChild(btn);
};
```

**load.php**

```php
function loadSources() {
    readfile('page1.html');
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>';
}

$_POST[loadSources()];
```

**page1.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="fromPage1.js"></script>
```

**fromPage1.js**

```js
console.log('from Page 1');
document.write('from Page 1');
```

**test.js**

```js
console.log('Testfile');
document.write('Testfile');
```

**Unexpected:** After clicking on the button Loading the scripts but the script **not** executed.

**Expected:** After clicking on the button Loading the scripts and the script are executed.

**Update**
this answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47614491/9050912

Comment: Why dont you just add more script tags to your html and call the functions inside files with onclick event?

Comment: FYI, a _Dome_ is half a sphere. What you mean here, is called DOM, and that stands for Document Object Model.

Comment: @CBroe thanks! this answer helped me:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47614491/9050912