# Create an simple XSS situation

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I want to create an simple XSS. Below is my code

```
<body> 
    <script>
        function update(){
            const message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            document.getElementById("show_message").innerHTML = message
        }
    </script>
    <h1 class="title">Cross-Site Scripting</h1>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" id="message"/><br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="update()">submit</button>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div id="root">
        You typed : 
        <span id="show_message">
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then I tried to type in `<script>alert(1);</script>`.But it didn't work. 
 Where's the problem?

Comment: `.innerHTML` does not execute code within `<script></script>`, consider using `document.write()` to execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `script` tag is not going to run because the browser is not going to let you do that. It is EXACTLY there to prevent such XSS attacks.

Anyway, if you want to see it run you can check other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml):

If you just want an input that can run, create one using `img`

```
<image/src/onerror=alert(8)>
```

[List](https://github.com/payloadbox/xss-payload-list)

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/gOKmrev?editors=1111)

Comment: yeah I've tried img tag so I was pretty confusing. now I got it. thx for your help

Comment: No worries. Feel free to accept the answer to complete the question

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code! Are you using Chrome? Chrome now uses [Trusted Types for DOM Manipulation](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5650088592408576). So it automatically protects you from this simple XSS attack.

By the way, if you want to try more XSS attacks, I recommend you play with the [seedlab](https://seedsecuritylabs.org/Labs_20.04/Web/Web_XSS_Elgg/).

Comment: yeah I'm using Chrome. thx for your help and information